# jQuery.load() wont show Google ads

Tags: jquery, adsense

I am loading a page which contains Google ads in to another page using jQuery's [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function.

But Google ads don't appear even though they do when I open the page itself.

What should I do?

EDIT:

Some code:

function load php page:

```
function get_fb(g) {

$("#hhs").load("hhs.php?rid="+g);

}
```

and that hhs.php contains the google ads code...

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ads are usually embedded via script tags and `$(...).load()` removes any script tags:

```
// inject the contents of the document in, removing the scripts
// to avoid any 'Permission Denied' errors in IE
.append(res.responseText.replace(rscript, ""))
```

`rscript` is a Regex matching script tags: `/<script(.|\s)*?\/script>/gi`

However, [AdSense for Ajax](http://code.google.com/intl/de/apis/afa/) might be what you need.

Comment: yeah but i dont think google will accept my application with 20.000 monthly view.

Comment: You are out of luck in that case.. the best solution would be putting the ads on the static part of the main page which is not reloaded dynamically.

Comment: It's not just jQuery, inserting `<script>` via `innerHTML` simply does not work in general. `<script>` blocks are only for scripts run during the page load/parse cycle; it makes no sense to try to load them into HTML later.