# How to refresh/get new google adsense content?

Tags: javascript, html, adsense

I have a website where new content is updated via ajax when the user scrolls down. A kind of infinite page where as long as the user is scrolling new data comes. I have an adsense skyscraper code on the side but its at the top of the page and I would like to refresh when new content is loaded through Ajax so that I can then position it more down. Is this possible? and is this legal? Here is a close example of what I need: http://imgur.com/gallery
As you can see they have an ad on the right and everytime new content is updated via scroll a new ad is shown as well as keeping the older one in place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6468298/744255

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not allowed. Read the [TOS](https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms) of adwords.

But a way to do it would be

```
var googleCode = '...your google code';
document.getElementById('googlediv').innerHTML(googlecode);
```

But, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/441425/295264) answer for more information.

Comment: @GabrielSantos, On that case, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/441425/295264)

Comment: And, please, read the TOS, item 5 "Prohibited Uses" https://www.google.com/adsense/localized-terms

Comment: @Zakukashi because they are not using Google Adsense. They are using something else.

Comment: @Zakukashi, You shouldn't try something not allowed from TOS

Answer (score 2):

Remember, it's Google's money going out from their bank account to yours.  They **DO** check websites at random to ensure they are in compliance, and they have and will continue to shut down websites whom they deem [and there is no superior court to go to, they make the final decision] to lock your account, withhold your earnings, and forever ban your (( CURRENT )) Google Adsense account.

The extra few   C E N T S   you could make vs. the risk of what you could lose -

The ultimate choice is yours.  May the force be with you. :o)