# Loading Google adsense after page load

Tags: javascript, adsense

My website has a page which loads content using ajax. I need to append google ads at the content of that request but conditionally. I know Google ads doesn't work with ajax because it makes second request using document.write which only works before page load complete. I thought of hacking the document.write and it actually works (atleast in firefox). **Can anyone please let me know if its against Google policies.**

```
$.ajax(function(){
  .....
  success: function(){
    document.write = function() {
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src = location.protocol + "//www.google.com/ads/search/module/ads/3.0/XXXX/n/search.js";
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    };
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = location.protocol + "//www.google.com/adsense/search/ads.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  }//Success end
});//Ajax end
```

FYI: Strings are hard-coded for explanation only.

Comment: Possible if you use DFP: have a look at https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/dfp/7MxNjJk46DQ and http://exisweb.net/how-to-use-google-adsense-on-a-responsive-website

Answer (score 0):

The violation of google terms and conditions has already been discussed in different threads regarding this topic ( ads refreshing ). [Refresh a Div that has a Google ad inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it) as an example has an answer which throws some light on a bit vague ( IMO ) google policy.

Well, apart from that google has already introduced an other tag model that is handling the situation of refreshing ads.

So the answer to the problem lies in new google ad tag that is called GPT - Google Publisher Tag
for information on GPT you can visit [Introduction to the Google Publisher Tag](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1649768?hl=en).
look at the [Sample Google Publisher Tag](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/1651549?hl=en&ref_topic=1651546)

and then finally [reloading ads without refreshing the whole page](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en&ref_topic=1651546)