# Refreshing google adsense on an AJAX page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know that directly refreshing the ads is against the **TOS** of **Google adsense** but I am wondering if it would be possible to use `java script` JUST to refresh the ads after 30 seconds or so on an `AJAX` themed website?

Currently if I display ads on my page they will disappear because of Google's 3 ads per page limit and because I am using `ajax` basically to keep my page from refreshing ever I am going to assume that it's not going to be possible to display **Google** **adsense** ads on my **website?**

Comment: https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refreshing your AdSense advertisements automatically isn't allowed. I understand that you only intend to refresh the ad in response to user action, but it still isn't allowed, even though it should be!

Remember, the reason why you want to update the advertisements is so that you can show new ones. Displaying an advertisement is called an "impression." When you use code to refresh the ads, you are automatically generating ad impressions.

[AdSense Program Policies state](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182) (emphasis mine):

See full answer [Refresh a Div that has a Google ad inside it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435391/refresh-a-div-that-has-a-google-ad-inside-it)

Answer (score 3):

See this post from Google. It has the code in to refresh the ad after an interval. Not quite as good as after the Ajax refresh but I guess if you are doing dynamic paging or something like that then the ad will refresh periodically at least.

https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en&ref_topic=4409240

Comment: Note that this answer uses DoubleClick not Adsense