# Google Adsense and Full Ajax site (like gmail.com, facebook.com, vk.com etc)

Tags: ajax, adsense

I have multilangual and fullajax site (http://musichearts.tv/)

Googlebot crawls the site to search for good, because what is displayed on the link "musichearts.tv/#!/url/to/part/" just absolutely in the same form and is available at "musichearts.tv/url/to/part/" (same but without hash # !)
I would like to clarify what will cause a violation of accommodation google ads on the site fullajax (again not the site that loads a piece of Ajax pages and there are ads, no. It is full-ajax site that simply displays a page faster than its regular version)
Will normally show relevant ads (eg Google knows keywords at musichearts.tv/url/to/part/, but when he needs to show ads on the page musichearts.tv/#!/url/to/part/ - he will understand that it's the same page and pick up relevant ads, or it will show ads, thinking that this is the main page musichearts.tv)
my site has an online radio player, so fullajax quite necessary that no matter what page we are - it always works and does not reload.
In fact the principle of operation fullajax on my site is the same as on facebook.com, gmail.com, etc. in this format can be safe to place ads?

Thank you for your answers and sorry for a lot of text :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can't place ads on ajax pages - there is no direct quote from Google but [ajax applications](https://developers.google.com/adsense-for-ajax/) are not accepted anymore.

[The guidelines](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?hl=en) also describe that

> Any method that artificially generates clicks or impressions on your Google ads is strictly prohibited. These prohibited methods include but are not limited to repeated manual clicks or impressions[...]

which means that you can't refresh the ads per ajax, even if you would use it for legit purposes.

More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12083756/3062017).

It is still possible with Google DFP tags, but I don't know exactly what that is, [here](https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en&ref_topic=4409240) is an example.