# Can't append <script> element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea why the piece of code below does not add the script element to the DOM?

```
var code = "<script></script>";
$("#someElement").append(code);
```

Comment: define "not working"- though I suspect the problem is that scripts aren't really part of the dom tree.

Comment: My bet is that the script node is being added to the DOM, but the browser just isn't executing the script.

Comment: Dan, how have you actually tested this?

Comment: @Joel - "not working" = it does not have any effect, i.e. the code within the script is not executed
@Outlaw Programmer - the node is not added to the DOM
@Jimmy Yes, I have tested it and it's not working

Answer (score 263, accepted):

I've seen issues where some browsers don't respect some changes when you do them directly (by which I mean creating the HTML from text like you're trying with the script tag), but when you do them with built-in commands things go better.  Try this:

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append( script );
```

From: [JSON for jQuery](http://mg.to/2006/01/25/json-for-jquery)

Comment: The <script> tag needs to be added to the DOM itself, not to the innerHTML of an existing element.

Comment: @Diodeus the innerHTML is part of the DOM and it's parsed on the fly by the browser, so this is a valid case.

Comment: Does this method work in all browsers? More specifically: does it work with webkit (Safari & Chrome)?

Comment: I believe it does, although to be honest I haven't tested in carefully in several months.

Comment: Another question: How can you pass variables to this script using this technique?

Comment: [Setting `script.type` is unnecessary.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet#type)

Comment: Don't just use jQuery's append if you really want the element to appear in the DOM. Use the native appendChild to achieve this.

Comment: `$("#someElement")[0].appendChild( script );`

Comment: FWIW, doing `$("<script src='myfile.js'></script>").appendTo("head");` works just fine for me in FF, Chrome, Safari, and iOS Safari

Comment: @MinqiPan, Your answer is the most correct one +1. Thanks.

Comment: Nothing worked for me, but combining answers on this page got me a working solution, I used @MinqiPan's `appendChild` method & included `script.innerHTML = "xxx";`

Answer (score 364):

**The Good News is:**

*It's 100% working.*

Just add something inside the script tag such as `alert('voila!');`. The right question you might want to ask perhaps, ***"Why didn't I see it in the DOM?"***.

Karl Swedberg has made a nice explanation to visitor's comment in [jQuery API site](http://api.jquery.com/append/#comment-61121802). I <strike>don't</strike> want to repeat all his words, you can read directly <strike>there</strike> here *(I found it hard to navigate through the comments there)*.

> *All of jQuery's insertion methods use
>   a domManip function internally to
>   clean/process elements before and
>   after they are inserted into the DOM.
>   One of the things the domManip
>   function does is pull out any script
>   elements about to be inserted and run
>   them through an "evalScript routine"
>   rather than inject them with the rest
>   of the DOM fragment. It inserts the
>   scripts separately, evaluates them,
>   and then removes them from the DOM.*
>
> *I believe that one of the reasons jQuery
>   does this is to avoid "Permission
>   Denied" errors that can occur in
>   Internet Explorer when inserting
>   scripts under certain circumstances.
>   It also avoids repeatedly
>   inserting/evaluating the same script
>   (which could potentially cause
>   problems) if it is within a containing
>   element that you are inserting and
>   then moving around the DOM.*

The next thing is, I'll summarize what's the bad news by using `.append()` function to add a script.

---

**And The Bad News is..**

*You can't debug your code.*

I'm not joking, even if you add `debugger;` keyword between the line you want to set as breakpoint, you'll be end up getting only the call stack of the object without seeing the breakpoint on the source code, *(not to mention that this keyword only works in webkit browser, all other major browsers seems to omit this keyword)*.

If you fully understand what your code does, than this will be a minor drawback. But if you don't, you will end up adding a `debugger;` keyword all over the place just to find out what's wrong with your (or my) code. Anyway, there's an alternative, don't forget that javascript can natively manipulate HTML DOM.

---

**Workaround.**

*Use javascript (not jQuery) to manipulate HTML DOM*

If you don't want to lose debugging capability, than you can use javascript native HTML DOM manipulation. Consider this example:

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "path/to/your/javascript.js";    // use this for linked script
script.text  = "alert('voila!');"               // use this for inline script
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

There it is, just like the old days isn't it. And don't forget to clean things up whether in the DOM or in the memory for all object that's referenced and not needed anymore to prevent memory leaks. You can consider this code to clean things up:

```
document.body.removechild(document.body.lastChild);
delete UnusedReferencedObjects; // replace UnusedReferencedObject with any object you created in the script you load.
```

The drawback from this workaround is that you may accidentally add a duplicate script, and that's bad. From here you can slightly mimic `.append()` function by adding an object verification before adding, and removing the script from the DOM right after it was added. Consider this example:

```
function AddScript(url, object){
    if (object != null){
        // add script
        var script   = document.createElement("script");
        script.type  = "text/javascript";
        script.src   = "path/to/your/javascript.js";
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        // remove from the dom
        document.body.removeChild(document.body.lastChild);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
};

function DeleteObject(UnusedReferencedObjects) {
    delete UnusedReferencedObjects;
}
```

This way, you can add script with debugging capability while safe from script duplicity. This is just a prototype, you can expand for whatever you want it to be. I have been using this approach and quite satisfied with this. Sure enough I will never use jQuery `.append()` to add a script.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! But was is "UnusedReferencedObjects"?

Comment: Thanks. I presume you were referring to the first occurrence of "UnusedReferencedObjects", that supposed to be any object you created in the script you load. I guess you better understand if you see what DeleteObject function does, it simply delete any object you passed to the function. I'll add some comment in the code to be clear. :)

Comment: Super post! The example of aCrosman didn't work for me and after ready your post I replaced $("#someElement").append(script);
with $("#someElement")[0].appendChild(script);
Which fixed it :) Thnx for the explantion

Comment: `$.getScript` is built into jQuery.

Comment: SourceURLs (http://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/) might help with debugging issues.

Comment: Nice answer, on a side note - console.log() may ease debugging and works fine in this case.

Comment: A better workaround is listed below and uses the same technique that Google analytics uses

Comment: Excellent description. Your code sample executes nicely, but I'm still trying to understand why this one doesn't: `var script = $('<script>alert(123);</script>')[0]; document.body.appendChild(script);`.

Comment: Thanks! The `script.text` is just what I'm looking for, since I need some variables in there.

Answer (score 24):

It is possible to dynamically load a JavaScript file using the [jQuery function `getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

```
$.getScript('http://www.whatever.com/shareprice/shareprice.js', function() {
  Display.sharePrice();
});
```

Now the external script will be called, and if it cannot be loaded it will gracefully degrade.

Comment: This does not insert anything into the DOM. It calls `eval()`.

Answer (score 21):

What do you mean "not working"?

jQuery detects that you're trying to create a SCRIPT element and will automatically run the contents of the element within the global context. Are you telling me that this doesn't work for you? -

```
$('#someElement').append('<script>alert("WORKING");</script>');
```

---

Edit: If you're not seeing the SCRIPT element in the DOM (in Firebug for example) after you run the command that's because jQuery, like I said, will run the code and then will delete the SCRIPT element - I believe that SCRIPT elements are always appended to the body... but anyway - placement has absolutely no bearing on code execution in this situation.

Comment: Amazing! There seems to be no vanilla native equivalent, but no despair as you can always [just load jQuery first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58473770/4829915).

Answer (score 20):

This works:

```
$('body').append($("<script>alert('Hi!');<\/script>")[0]);
```

It seems like jQuery is doing something clever with scripts so you need to append the html element rather than jQuery object.

Comment: THis is the only solution that works in my case.  The other sol'ns above depend on javascript code present ahead of time in the html file.  Since I'm adding code dynamically, such javascript code can't be known ahead of time!  THANKS Darwin!!

Comment: [James' code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/611042/4829915) worked even better for me. Not only because it requires neither `$()`, `[0]`, nor escaping (e.g. `\/script`), but because the code here for some reason can't handle multiple tags (e.g, multiple scripts), while @James' can.

Answer (score 15):

Try this may be helpful:

```
var fileref=document.createElement('script');
fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
fileref.setAttribute("src","scriptAnalytics.js");
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
```

Comment: no idea why this guy negatives hes the only one not stupid enough to keep using jquery for everything!

Comment: Probably most of the answers uses jQuery because in the question the OP is using jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

I want to do the same thing but to append a script tag in other frame!

```
var url = 'library.js'; 
var script = window.parent.frames[1].document.createElement('script' ); 
script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
script.src = url;
$('head',window.parent.frames[1].document).append(script);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
    ...
    ...jQuery("<script></script>")...
    ...
</script>
```

The `</script>` within the string literal terminates the entire script, to avoid that `"</scr" + "ipt>"` can be used instead.

Comment: Or don't embed your javascript directly within the HTML document. External script files don't have this problem.

Comment: Escape sequences: `"\x3cscript\x3e\x3c/script\x3e"`. In XHTML, you only need to put in a commented-out CDATA block.

Comment: It’s rather the `</` that’s not allowed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Answer (score 2):

Adding the sourceURL in the script file helped as mentioned in this page:
https://blog.getfirebug.com/2009/08/11/give-your-eval-a-name-with-sourceurl/

1. In the script file, add a statement with sourceURL like "//@ sourceURL=foo.js"
2. Load the script using jQuery $.getScript() and the script will be available in "sources" tab in chrome dev tools

Answer (score 1):

Your script is executing , you just can't use `document.write` from it. Use an alert to test it and avoid using `document.write`. The statements of your js file with `document.write` will not be executed and the rest of the function will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I think is the best solution. Google Analytics is injected this way.

```
var (function(){
    var p="https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://";
        d=document,
        g=d.createElement('script'),
        s=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        g.type='text/javascript';
        g.src=p+'url-to-your-script.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s); })();
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery to create a [Script DOM Element](https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/). It can be done with vanilla ES6 like so:

```
const script = "console.log('Did it work?')"
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){
      a=s.createElement(o),m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
      a.innerText=g;
      a.onload=r;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)}
  )(window,document,'script',script, resolve())
}).then(() => console.log('Sure did!'))
```

It doesn't need to be wrapped in a `Promise`, but doing so allows you to resolve the promise when the script loads, helping prevent race conditions for long-running scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Append script to body:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("<script>", {  src : "bootstrap.min.js",  type : "text/javascript" }).appendTo("body");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it if you want to append code is using the `document.createElement` method but then using `.innerHTML` instead of `.src`.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.innerHTML = 'alert("Hey there... you just appended this script to the body");';
$("body").append( script );
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/8746125) and works fine. Just replace the `<` symbol with that `\x3C`.

```
// With Variable
var code = "\x3Cscript>SomeCode\x3C/script>";
$("#someElement").append(code);
```

**or**

```
//Without Variable
$("#someElement").append("\x3Cscript>SomeCode\x3C/script>");
```

You can test the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cu71n5z3/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Can try like this

```
var code = "<script></" + "script>";
$("#someElement").append(code);
```

The only reason you can't do `"<script></script>"` is because the string  isn't allowed inside javascript because the DOM layer can't parse what's js and what's HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an `npm` package that lets you take an HTML string, **including script tags** and append it to a container while **executing the scripts**

Example:

```
import appendHtml from 'appendhtml';

const html = '<p>Hello</p><script src="some_js_file.js"></script>'; 
const container = document.getElementById('some-div');

await appendHtml(html, container);

// appendHtml returns a Promise, some_js_file.js is now loaded and executed (note the await)
```

Find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/appendhtml

Answer (score 0):

```
/* SELECTOR */


$T = document.getElementsByTagName.bind( document );


/* INCLUDE */


function include( file_js )
{
    // Create script
    var s       = document.createElement( "script" );
        s.src   = file_js;
        s.type  = "text/javascript";
        s.defer = true;

    // Append script
    $T( "head" ).item(0).appendChild( s );
}

 /* TEST CODE */


<script>
    include( "<? echo ROOT ?>/lib/js/test.js" ); // Test.js contains: console.log( "Hello World" );
</script>


/* RESULT (in Google Chrome DevTool: Elements) */


    <script src="http://localhost/mysite/lib/js/test.js" type="text/javascript" defer></script>
</head>


/* RESULT (in Google Chrome DevTool: Console) */


Hello World
```

[Defer attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp): a script that will be downloaded in parallel to parsing the page, and executed after the page has finished parsing:

Answer (score -1):

Just create an element by parsing it with jQuery.

```
<div id="someElement"></div>
<script>
    var code = "<script>alert(123);<\/script>";
    $("#someElement").append($(code));
</script>
```

Working example: https://plnkr.co/edit/V2FE28Q2eBrJoJ6PUEBz

Comment: This still has the same problem, some browsers do not respect this.

Comment: Could you please let me know what browsers and what version of jQuery are you using? Thanks!