# Can I create script tag by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a script tag by jQuery.

I use the following code:

```
$("<body>").append("<script></script>");
```

It doesn't work.
What will you do to achieve it?

Comment: I'm just interested: why would you do that? You're already running JavaScript code, so why do you need another block?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Comment: I want to load another javascript file after loading the page.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You should do it like so

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src=url;

$("body").append(script);
```

Comment: Can I ask why would you not use a jQuery based solution when you are using jQuery? getScript will work, you should try it. lol

Answer (score 41):

To load from a url:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
  src: url
}))
```

To load from existing source code:

```
$("body").append($("<script />", {
  html: code
}))
```

Answer (score 16):

Why are you not using [jQuery.getScript(url,[callback])](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript)?

Comment: I want to load another javascript which the javascript is in another domain.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer, or it should at least be written as an answer rather than as a question. It's not clearly certain that `getScript()` can do everything that's possible with creating script tags. And if it is, the answer would be much better if it actually stated that.

Answer (score 12):

The error is in the selector:

```
$("body").append("<script>alert('hello world');<\/script>");
```

Note that you have to escape the unallowed characters in the appended string.

Answer (score 2):

This can help, who end up here after 8 years

```
$('<script>alert("hi");</' + 'script>').appendTo(body);
```

The only reason you can't do `$('<script></script>')` is because the string  isn't allowed inside javascript because the DOM layer can't parse what's js and what's html.