# Inject external javascript file in html body after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, delayed-execution

I want to load an external javascript after page is loaded. Actually the javascript contains source for an ad and its making page load slow. All I want is to delay loading & execution of ads to make sure fast page load.

thanks,
Bilal

Comment: Have you tried putting the `<script>` at the end of the document, just before `</body>`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You may just use this script at the last tag of your body block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.setAttribute('src', 'http://yourdomian.com/your_script.js');
   script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
</script>
```

Comment: this will not show ads that are loaded by the external script.

Comment: Improve of the last line: `document.head.appendChild(script)`

Answer (score 6):

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.type='text/javascript';
script.src=url;

$("body").append(script);
```

[Courtsey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

Comment: There is no need to use jQuery at this point. `document.body.appendChild(script);`

Comment: this will not show ads that are loaded by the external script.

Comment: The script does not become immediately available (using the jQuery and non-jQuery approaches) so this isn't a universal solution. You would either need to use a library like async or use the jQuery getScript method with a promise (see below).

Answer (score 2):

I would look at using asynchronous Javascript loading. There are frameworks for this such as [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Answer (score 2):

$("#selector").click(function(){ 
  $.getScript("YourScript.js"); 
});

Then Run what is implemented in that script

Comment: Same as above, this loads async so to be stable, you must use an sync library or promises for example:  $.getScript( url ).then( function() {  //won't be called until the script is actually loaded });

Answer (score 0):

Without using something like jQuery getScript() and a promise or a proper loading library like requireJS, the script can be included in the page, but will load async so there's no guarantee it will be ready when you need it. If you're already using jQuery, the simple answer is then:

```
$.getScript( scriptUrl ).then( function() {
  //do this ONLY after the script is fully loaded
});
```