# PageSpeed Insights tells me that I have to optimize files that do not exist

Tags: php, wordpress, pagespeed

I just deleted all the entries referring to these files and the pagespeed still keeps telling me to optimize them, but they do not exist anymore, I deleted the cache, the site hosted by wpengine.

```
https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js (15 minutes)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
```

Source Code
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PageSpeed Insights 99/100 because of Google Analytics - How can I cache GA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162881/pagespeed-insights-99-100-because-of-google-analytics-how-can-i-cache-ga)

Comment: Your plugins/host/theme could be injecting those links into your markup somewhere. Just make sure you've done a view source to be positive they're not.

Comment: host can insert a code in the index and hide ??

Comment: Obsidian Age, this problem is different i dont have any entry analytcs.js

Comment: more than likely being pulled in via a plugin as opposed to being in your code.