# Who can I get HTTP_USER_AGENT of GTmetrix and Pingdom?

Tags: user-agent, pingdom, gtmetrix

Do anyone know who can I get the HTTP_USER_AGENT of Testing Tools like GTmetrix and pingdom. To be more precise please check this link which get the User agent of Google Pagespeed => [PageSpeed Insights 99/100 because of Google Analytics - How can I cache GA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162881/pagespeed-insights-99-100-because-of-google-analytics-how-can-i-cache-ga/36137447#36137447)

I want to get same thing for GTmetrix and Pingdom. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please refer https://www.365andup.com/

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches the UA as of the time of this answer:

```
// javascript PSI regex
navigator.userAgent.match(/nux.*oto\sG|x11.*fox\/54|x11.*ome\/39|x11.*ome\/62|oid\s6.*1.*xus\s5.*MRA58N.*ome|JWR66Y.*ome\/62|woobot|speed|ighth|tmetr|eadle/i)
// taken from WP plugin Fast Velocity Minify
```

Hope it helps