# Set expiration browser date for external file in htaccess

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, caching, cache-control

I'd like to optimize my website for Google.
I've load the external js file for analytics.
Other files I made mod_expires in .htaccess but I don't know how to do with in this case.

Google tells me that:

> Take advantage of browser caching
>
> If you set an expiration date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers for
>   static resources, the browser loads previously downloaded resources
>   from the local disk instead of from the network.
>
> Use browser caching for the following cacheable resources:
>
> http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)

I really apprentice who will help me.

**edited with what I have now**

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>

    ExpiresActive on
    ExpiresDefault                                      "access plus 1 month"

  # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 1 year"

  # Data interchange
    ExpiresByType application/atom+xml                  "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rdf+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"
    ExpiresByType application/rss+xml                   "access plus 1 hour"

    ExpiresByType application/json                      "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/ld+json                   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/schema+json               "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.geo+json              "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xml                       "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/xml                              "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
    ExpiresByType image/vnd.microsoft.icon              "access plus 1 week"
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon                          "access plus 1 week"

  # HTML
    ExpiresByType text/html                             "access plus 0 seconds"

  # JavaScript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript                "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript              "access plus 1 year"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript                       "access plus 1 year"

  # Manifest files
    ExpiresByType application/manifest+json             "access plus 1 year"

    ExpiresByType application/x-web-app-manifest+json   "access plus 0 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest                   "access plus 0 seconds"

  # Media files
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/bmp                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/gif                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml                         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/webp                            "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/mp4                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/ogg                             "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType video/webm                            "access plus 1 month"

  # Web fonts

    # Embedded OpenType (EOT)
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject         "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/eot                              "access plus 1 month"

    # OpenType
    ExpiresByType font/opentype                         "access plus 1 month"

    # TrueType
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf                "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 1.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff                 "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff               "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType font/woff                             "access plus 1 month"

    # Web Open Font Format (WOFF) 2.0
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff2                "access plus 1 month"

  # Other
    ExpiresByType text/x-cross-domain-policy            "access plus 1 week"

</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's much harder to set it in htaccess without plugin, will you consider sending the header via php?

Comment: That's ok but what should I do in php with the load of external files?

Comment: so you want to cache the analytics.js to the client's browser?

Comment: I'd like to set an expiration date for the static resourse analytics.js on google server

Comment: I think you won't be able to set cache expire on google server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

[PageSpeed Insights 99/100 because of Google Analytics - How can I cache GA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162881/pagespeed-insights-99-100-because-of-google-analytics-how-can-i-cache-ga)

Here is the solution:

```
<?php if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Speed Insights') === false): ?>
// your analytics code here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess**

```
# 1 Month for all your static assets
 <filesMatch ".(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesMatch>

 # 1 DAYS for rss feeds and robots
 <filesMatch ".(xml|txt)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>

 # 4 HOURS for your real articles files
 <filesMatch ".(html|htm)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=14400, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
```

Comment: I edit with what I have now, unluckily with what you write me I still have the problem. I simply add your code above what I copy-pasted in the question (edited).