# Is Google analytics script worth removing to improve my page speed?

Tags: pagespeed

I have an image heavy art site and my FID score needs improving. The new Google algorithm taking place in June is  going to punish me for having pages that take 256ms to load , but google analytics script takes up 156ms of that.
Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove only if you think Google Analytics is not important for you, There are some hacks which I personally do not recommend to resolve GA script issue shown in PSI but if you still wishes to resolve you can find helpful answers in this post. [PageSpeed Insights 99/100 because of Google Analytics - How can I cache GA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162881/pagespeed-insights-99-100-because-of-google-analytics-how-can-i-cache-ga)