# How can you include Javascript and css files only in the case that they are not already included?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a big legacy web application.  I am adding some JavaScript in it that has dependencies on a few js files and a css file.  These files may or may not already be included on the pages I am adding the new JavaScript to.

Is there a way I can include these Javascript and css files into a page only in the case that they have not been added?

Answer (score 1):

Check for the existence of the library and load it if not present *and* necessary:

```
if (!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "jquery-1.7.min.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(script);
}

...
```

Comment: That'll be a *ReferenceError* if there's no `jQuery` declared. Use `if (!window.jQuery) {` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could write Javascript to search for the script tag, and link tag for the JS and CSS respectively. If not found, you could insert the tags into your HTML.

How to insert tags:
[Can I create script tag by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Look into [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/KeyboardEvent) and then set their attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options:

**JavaScript**

Check if a particular method is undefined and then append the script to `head`.

```
if (typeof method === 'undefined') {
  var script = document.createElement('script'),
      head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'path/to/js/file.js';
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Or, you can loop through each of the `script` elements to check if the `src` is equal to what you need to add:

Use [Mozilla's `indexOf` extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to search `sourceArr` for the `src` of the JS file you want to include.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
  Array.prototype.indexOf = function (searchElement /*, fromIndex */ ) {
    "use strict";
    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError();
    }
    var t = Object(this);
    var len = t.length >>> 0;
    if (len === 0) {
      return -1;
    }
    var n = 0;
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
      n = Number(arguments[1]);
      if (n != n) { // shortcut for verifying if it's NaN
        n = 0;
      } else if (n != 0 && n != Infinity && n != -Infinity) {
        n = (n > 0 || -1) * Math.floor(Math.abs(n));
      }
    }
    if (n >= len) {
      return -1;
    }
    var k = n >= 0 ? n : Math.max(len - Math.abs(n), 0);
    for (; k < len; k++) {
      if (k in t && t[k] === searchElement) {
        return k;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

To use this, do the following:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    sourceArr = [],
    i = 0;
for (i = scripts.length; i--;) {
  var source = scripts[i].src;
  sourceArr.push(source);
}
if (sourceArr.indexOf('path/to/js/file.js') === -1) {
  var script = document.createElement('script'),
      head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'path/to/js/file.js';
  head.appendChild(script);
}
```

You could use the above for your CSS files, as well. Just loop through each of the `link` elements and set `cssFile.type = 'text/css'` and add `cssFile.rel = 'stylesheet'`.