# Methods of JavaScript injection using Objective-C

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, code-injection

I'm looking for different methods of injecting JavaScript into a WebView (in Cocoa).

I am trying to inject some javascript into the `<head>` tag of a HTML file that has been loaded into the WebView.

The following method doesn't work for me. It seems to only work with very simple JavaScript with **no nested brackets** (from what I have tested):

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"var script = document.createElement('script');"
                                                     "script.type = 'text/javascript';"
                                                     "script.text = \"some simple JavaScript"
                                                     "}\";"
                                                     "document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);"]];
```

Are there any other ways of doing this with more complicated JavaScript / jQuery functions?

The full code I am trying to inject is as follows:

```
function submitFormForTime(time){
    $(\".t_h\").each(function(i, obj) {
        if ($(this).text() != time) return;
        $(this).parent().find(\"form\").each(function(i, obj){
            obj.submit();
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use jQuery to add `<script>` tags. This has been asked many times. See:

- [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)
- [Can I create script tag by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

You can do it with browser built-in functions, BUT:

Would it work to just assign your function to a variable on your page and then evaluate it? Something like:

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    // add function to page:
    NSString * js = @"myFunction = function(){ return \"success!\"; }" ;
    [ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js ] ;

    // execute newly added function:
    NSString * result = [ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction();"] ;
    NSLog(@"result=\"%@\"", result) ;
}
```

**update** explicit examples:

You should use my above example as a template!

Anyway, there's 2 parts to the process... The Javascript part and the Objective-C part. At the Javascript level, you are doing this:

```
// assign a function to the variable "someFunction":
var someFunction = function(){...};

// call the function in the variable "someFunction":
someFunction();
```

You can also do it without assigning the function to a variable, for example, if you don't care about referring to the function in the future. Doing it without a variable and using an anonymous function looks like this:

```
( function(){...} )() ;
```

i.e. instead of doing `var A = <the function>; A();` you are doing `(<the function>)();`

Finally, if your anonymous function takes arguments, like yours does, the pattern looks like this:

```
( function(var0, ..., varN){...} )(arg0, ..., argN);
```

Using that as a template for your code, your JS ends up like:

```
( function(time) {
    $(\".t_h\").each(function(i, obj) 
    {
        if ($(this).text() != time)  return;

        $(this).parent().find(\"form\").each(function(i, obj) {
            obj.submit();
        });
    });
})( 123.456 );
```

So, that's what you want the web view to execute... That's the code we pass to the webview. But you have to build that string in your Obj-C program, with the "complication" of inserting the current time argument (`123.456` in the above code).

It looks like this:

```
NSString * jsTemplate =
    @"( function(time) {"
    @"        $(\".t_h\").each(function(i, obj) {"
    @"            if ($(this).text() != time)  return;"
    @"            $(this).parent().find(\"form\").each(function(i, obj) {"
    @"                obj.submit();"
    @"            });"
    @"        });"
    @"    })( %g );" ;
NSString * js = [ NSString stringWithFormat:jsTemplate, 123.456 ] ;
NSString * result = [ webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js ] ;
```

I think I've written enough now :)

Comment: Your above example works, and result="success!" is printed in the console. However, when I use my own javascript instead of "success", blank quotation marks are printed in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to run your function once, change your code to be `(function(){...})()`

Comment: If you are going to use your function multiple times, use 2 steps. Assign your function to a variable (`submitFormForTime = function(time){...}`) then each time you want to execute your function do `submitFormForTime(...)`.

Comment: You have to modify your code to do one of the above. My example is based on the two step version

Comment: Wait, to have the function run only once, could you clarify it for me please?

Answer (score 0):

I would get all the HTML from web view, then I'd inject the code and reload the page. It's still not a proper method of injection, but it may work.

```
NSString *htmlDataString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
// use nsstring methds to find the place for injecting
// inject avascript code
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlDataString baseURL:nil];
```

Of course you may have base URL from your request, if so replace that nil.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't tried this, but if the problem is with the brackets and the complexity of the code, you can try calling a JS file stored in the bundle. Maybe it solves that. For example:

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@”submitFormForTime” ofType:@”js”]];

NSString *jsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:fileData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

Maybe setting the encoding type helps to parse all the brackets in a right way.