# <script> tag showing blank when sent as message

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I have created one chatting application using signalR. Everything works fine for me. But there is a small problem while sending message.
When i send **script** tag as message, its showing blank in my chat window.

My code for appending message to chat window like below

```
$('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + fromUserName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');
```

The message is going to server side as string like "`<script>`", but when appending its showing nothing.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to let people send scripts through the chat?

Comment: @Juhana: That's his exact problem. He *doesn't* want to, but because he's parsing it as HTML rather than text, he is.

Comment: Try to send `string` not `HTML` or string that should not contain `< or >` and say what u got?

Comment: I want to send <script> as message while chatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your message is being parsed as HTML. You can either escape the HTML entities on the server (depending on your server side language, but preferred regardless), or you can use text nodes to set the `textContent` of the message, rather than HTML;

```
var markup = $(jQuery.parseHTML('<div class="message"><span class="userName"></span></div'));

markup.find('.userName').text(fromUserName);
markup.append(document.createTextNode(message));

$('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append(markup);
```

... but just to emphasize, you should *really* be encoding this on the server.

Comment: Its giving me error "TypeError: markup.find is not a function".

Comment: @akeeseth: Eugh sorry, forgot `parseHTML` returned an array rather than a jQuery object... fixed.

Answer (score -1):

First look at google results would show You the answer.

```
var url = "your script url";
var message = document.createElement('script');
message.type = 'text/javascript';
message.src = url;
$('#' + ctrId).find('#divMessage').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + fromUserName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div>');
```

http://mg.to/2006/01/25/json-for-jquery

[Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

[Can I create script tag by jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

Comment: I don't understand why my answer got a downvote. It fixes the problem and I don't find it vulgar or anything...