# Cannot add script node dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to attach a `<script>` node with the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('body').append('<script>alert(\'foo\');</script>');
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the code

```
alert('foo');
```

to be added an executed, but actually, the following string is added

```
');
```

What is happening here?

Comment: Because it ends the script tag earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/142985

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I create script tag by jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to properly escape the slash character here and use doublequotes for foo:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('body').append('<script>alert("foo");<\/script>');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to break `</script>` inside the string or it will considered as the end tag for `<script>`.

```
  $('body').append('<script>alert(\'foo\');</scr'+'ipt>');
```