# Add javascript with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a div has zero height, I try to add a javascript code.

HTML:

```
<div class="med_rec"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
    if ($(".med_rec").height() === 0) {

 $('.med_rec').text('<script type="text/javascript"  src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/publishertag.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
Criteo.DisplayAd({
"zoneid": 11111,
"async": false});
</script>')    

}
```

I tried it with

```
</' + 'script>
```

but there is always a syntax error.

Thank you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create script tag by jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1199676/can-i-create-script-tag-by-jquery)

Comment: Maybe the error occurs in your external script file.

Comment: @labu77 please try updates solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the problem was with : '<' and '>'

Use this:

```
$('.med_rec').append('\<script type="text/javascript"  src="//static.criteo.net/js/ld/publishertag.js"\>\</script\><script type="text/javascript">Criteo.DisplayAd({"zoneid": 11111,"async": false});\</script\>');
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: I tried it already with append but still syntax error. Maybe you can add it in a html file to see it self? thank you

Comment: Indeed M8. Its Fixed! Thank you very much. Very nice!

Comment: No problem. Happy Coding!