# Loading an external script after page load with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a little confused how to do this, basically I have a page that has a Facebook Share button inserted via JavaScript:

```
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The problem is that it's blocking the page load at that part, how can I insert this tag after page load and still have the script execute? I'll like to do it in an unobtrusive way, ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the jQuery [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) command inside [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). This will download the script after the page has loaded. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript("http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share", function() {
        alert("Script loaded and executed.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [jquery.getScripts](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load it asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
    script.src = "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share";
    script.onload=optionallyDoSomethingWithTheScriptYouJustLoaded();//not needed
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
    headID.appendChild(script);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Inject the script tag**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element) into the dom as a callback of the [**document ready**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) event.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
$(function() {
  $.getScript('http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share', function() {
    //do nothing here
  });
});
```