# Jquery - Custom js files for desktop monitor and iPad...?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad

I've got a Question for you - That i've been thinking about for a period.... And I hope that you'll help me out....
Pleeeeaaase....

What to do ??? -  I'm having a site with all of its content, everything is good and well...
and I have targeted a normal desctop monitor, and ipad.... Nice Nice....

Included a reference to jquery on google api...... But i want to use 2 different customized js files. Because i want to us one js file for the interaction, on the monitor. And 1 js file for interaction on iPad...

How do I go about this one ?????????

In Advance - Thank You.... Hope to see some kind of feedback to this dillema....

Comment: Argh! Use feature detection, not device detection. Why should an Android tablet user get a different experience to an iOS tablet user?

Answer (score 2):

The first part of your question is answered here: [Detect iPad users using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617638/detect-ipad-users-using-jquery)

The second part is answered here: [Loading an external script after page load with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881164/loading-an-external-script-after-page-load-with-jquery)