# fancybox safari issue when loading external page

Tags: safari, fancybox

I'm having an issue with fancybox when I try and load an html page.

I have a link

```
<a href="testPage.html" id="chal">Load testPage.html in fancybox</a>
```

and then the js that binds it to fancybox

```
$('a#chal').fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    showCloseButton: true,
    scrolling: 'no',
    opacity: 0.5,
    centerOnScroll:true
});
```

In chrome, firefox, and IE the fancybox loads fine. But in Safari, the html loads without the accompanying css or js. If I add something like this, then it works:

```
 $('a#chal').click(function() {
    $("head").append($("<link rel='stylesheet' href='blah.css' media='screen' />"); 
    });
```

Then it works just fine but it seems like the solution above is not the way to go about it. Is there any other way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found very limited info on this bug, so thanks for pointing out that Safari rips out js/css elements in fancybox popups. I tried your method and the [createElement('script') method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element) but I struggled to get your method working with js includes as it was doing funky things with my own script.

As a last resort I moved my custom jquery scripts that were previously in the head element of the popup to the body element (not good form I know... ;) and now all my form validation and ajax posts work in Chrome/Safari/FF/IE7/IE8.

HTH someone out there.

Cheers,
Ben