# How to add a <script> element to the DOM and execute its code?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a  element into the existing DOM to have the javascript code run.

I did this with YUI:

```
var scriptNode = Y.Node.create('<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">alert("Hello world!");<\/script>');
var headNode = Y.one('head');
headNode.append(scriptNode);
```

It's successfully added to the DOM but it doesn't give me an alert.

Someone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Any reason why you don't run the JS directly?

Comment: Is the Javascript in `scriptNode` under your control?  Wrap it in a function and call it after appending it?  Just found this - seems appropriate and informative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element/3603496#3603496

Comment: Your closing tag has an extra '\', it should be </script>, not sure if this effects it

Comment: SharpPer - the backslash quotes the following forward slash so that `</` in the string isn't mistaken for the closing tag of the enclosing script element. It is consdered good practice for closing tags in string literals.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I have no idea how YUI's `Node.create()` function works, so no comment on that. But a simple cross-browser script is:

```
  window.onload = function() {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    var code = 'alert("hello world!");';
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.body.appendChild(s);
    }
  }
```

The *try..catch* block is necessary as most browsers like the first method but some don't and throw an error. The second method covers those.  You can also simply *eval* the code, which is more or less equivalent and what some libraries do.

Comment: Can't you put document.body.appendChild(s) under a finally clause?

Comment: Yes, that's fine as the error is caused by appending the text node to a script element.

Comment: If the catch block code satisfies more browsers, then why not simply use that?

Comment: Note that if you eval the code instead of adding a script element, [document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) will not be set properly. If you are making a tool for other people to use, their script code might depend on `document.currentScript`

Comment: Why can't you just use the second method then? Some browsers don't work with the second method?

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69690190/how-can-i-add-a-minified-js-script-to-the-dom-and-execute-it

Answer (score 13):

I found this function in the JQuery source, which seems to do what you want and feels a bit cleaner than the other approaches to me. But then again I am a JS beginner and probably don't see the details. Anyways, somebody might take something useful away from this.

```
function DOMEval( code, doc ) {
    doc = doc || document;

    var script = doc.createElement( "script" );

    script.text = code;
    doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
}
```

Comment: What is with the removeChild call? Wouldn't that remove the script you just added? Is there a trick I'm missing?

Comment: @Danger It appends the code in a script tag, it executes immediately, then the script tag is removed to clean up. The function is called DOMEval, not addScript, etc.

Comment: Using the `createTextNode` was appending the code as a string. Your solution of adding the code via the `text` property was the good one for me.