# Dynamically add script tag to JSP document and set script body

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp, dynamic

I understand one can from within javascript add a  tag a html/JSP document... Like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'http://s/s.js';
document.body.appendChild( s );
</script>
```

But is there a way to add some script to the **body** of that script tag you created? Like:

```
s.body = "alert('hello');"
```

Comment: and why would you be doing that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run

Comment: Lol everyone is asking me that... It's hard to explain. I have a JSP document, with a button and a div, with the button onClick it calls a JS function that then goes to the server and dynamically generates JS Code, it then stores it in a var. e.g. var jsCode = "alert('hello');". This is just an example of course but in my project that generated script actually goes and populates the div with some content. So in essence, how to I get that var jsCode, to go back to my JSP page and execute?

Comment: This would've been easy if is wasn't a onClick event but a form submission, that way when the JSP page loaded again I could easily do that.. But it's an Ajax call... :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
   s.innerHTML ="_satellite.pageBottom();";
```

Try this.