# How to include jQuery library in Javascript without <script src="">

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to include jQuery library in javascript file (john.js) remotely. I have tried this without any luck;

```
(function(d, t) {
    var g = d.createElement(t), // create a script tag
        s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; // find the first script tag in the document
    g.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'; // set the source of the script to your script
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s); // append the script to the DOM
}(document, 'script'));

$( document ).ready(function() {

// My jquery works here

});
```

I want to fetch a script in javascript way. What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: Have you looked at jQuery's getScript() function? http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: I want to fetch Jquery, not js. And how you can use, when you havent include the jquery library ? getScript() is a jQuery function, not javascript.

Comment: But have you looked at `getScript()` in the sense of examining its code to see how it works?

Comment: I know that script mate. But As I said, Its JQUERY function. I need to make it in javascript way.

Comment: jQuery is written 100% in JavaScript, so obviously anything jQuery can do is doable in plain JavaScript. So, again, if you examine the jQuery source code for `getScript()` you can see how it works and include some version of that yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is that JQuery is not loaded yet when this code is executed:

```
$(document).ready(function() { .. }
```

As is, you get an error like this: `$ is undefined` (or similar)

You should use the `onload` event of created script element to be sure it is loaded Jquery.

This sample shown how you can achieve your goal. Good Luck.

```js
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
newScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js'; // set the source of the script to your script
newScript.onload = function() {
  alert("Script is ready!");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("JQuery is ready!");
  });
};
var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
head.appendChild(newScript);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of an `XMLHttpRequest` and `eval` to fetch the javascript file dynamically like `getScript` does for jQuery.

See my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/risto1/v7882csg/).

Comment: No, I want to fetch Jquery, not js. getScript is a jquery function, and it cant work when you havent include the jQuery Library

Comment: As of my knowledge, xmlhttprequest sends request to a webpage, how can that fetch the script. Possible to show me a quick example ?

Comment: See my fiddle. Don't forget to accept and/or upvote my answer if it answered your question! I'm looking to get some points.

Comment: absolutely no need to use eval to do this

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer on how to fetch, coming from an other post :

[Adding <script> element to the DOM and have the javascript run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run)

That beeing said another issue you may have is that when you call your

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

// My jquery works here

});
```

Jquery may not be loaded yet

so you can try a recursive function to check if jquery has been loaded with something like that (not teste)...

```
function launch(callBack){
    if (window.jQuery) {  
       callBack();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function(){launch(callBack);},100);
    }
}
launch(function(){
   $( document ).ready(function() {
     // My jquery works here
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically the jquery is called in the html file before custom javascript files are called:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```