# How to pass value from on javascript to another javascript file when I pass value in function?

Tags: javascript, php

`<a href="#" onclick="passid(idvalue)" class="generate">Generate ID</a>`

Above is my php code from where I pass id value in a JavaScript Function

```
function passid(id)
{
var gener = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
             var id = "+id+"<\/script>
             <script src=\"http://mySample.com/MYjs/myJS.js\"><\/script>"; 
document.getElementById('codegen').textContent = gener ; 
}
```

from this I want to pass ID in `myJS.js` File How to send this ID.

Comment: You are messing up things.. Just call a function from that file having argument as `id`

Comment: What I want to do is Pass this ID in my another javascript file `myJS.js` don't want to call a function from that file.

Comment: What will you do of that file ? If you are not gonna use it in function ?

Comment: After Passing the ID from here I am viewing a popup by using `myJS.js` from database. and can you explain with code what you are saying because I am not getting it exactly. Sorry

Comment: Then just keep is as `global` which could be accessed from anywhere...

Comment: I don't want to access it in the same file I want it in another **JavaScript** file which will use ID to send in a `.php` file from where using query it will get a specific ID popup to display

Comment: Then do not access it in current file.. What I said is _It is accessible_

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116556/discussion-between-dharit-soni-and-rayon).

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Jquery?

```
$('.generate').on('click', function () {
passid(1);
});

function passid(id) {
    var gener = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var id = "+id+";alert(id);<\/script>"+"<script>alert(id);<\/script>"+"<script src=\"alert.js\"><\/script>";//Alert inside JS file too!
    $(gener).appendTo(document.body);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LeroyRon/bk9fryuj/

///No jQuery version 
Look around to here: [Adding <script> element to the DOM and have the javascript run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run)

Answer (score -1):

Just make id global variable and to change html you need to use innerHTML:

```
function passid(id) {
    window.id = id;
    var gener = "<script src=\"http://mySample.com/MYjs/myJS.js\"><\/script>"; 
    document.getElementById('codegen').innerHTML = gener; 
}
```

Comment: This is not as what I want. As I cleared in my question I want to use ID in another JavaScript File **myJS.js**

Comment: @DharitSoni To use variable in another script you make it global so other script can access it. Scripts share same global variables. And `<script>var id = 10</script>` is the same as `window.id = 10;`