# React-Native: Injecting javascript dynamically in webview on runtime

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, webview, react-native

I am currently working on a project where I need to load the user in a webview, in the same time I'm injecting a javascript code to check if tokens expired. Everything works till here, I am getting a message back from the webview that we need to refresh but I cannot figure out how I can inject javascript on runtime in the webview. I am using at the moment this module: https://github.com/alinz/react-native-webview-bridge.

Is there a way how to make this flow working? So like this the tokens will not expire if the user is using the application.

Comment: I did managed to make it work, ill post soon my repo with my result.

Comment: How did you make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just insert a new script element into the page's body?

Perhaps something like the answer to this question: [Adding <script> element to the DOM and have the javascript run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run)

Comment: I don't think this can help in my project as I need to receive a new token in my react-native app in the runtime.