# How to add local variables and a different function in script element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, createelement

I need to create a script element as below,

```html
<div class="abcd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
  var a = "10";
  var b = "20";

        (function(d) {
            //lines of code of the function
        }(document));
    </script>
</div>
```

I have tried to complete these so by first creating a script element by document.Createelement option. and adding this script part into the div. But not able to add the code part within the script part.

Need to add both var code part and also the function.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

---

EDIT ----

I am using below code now,

```html
    var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var divElm = document.createElement('div');
    var scpt = document.createElement('script');
    scpt.type = 'text/javascript';
    var clName= "TEST";


    var myfunc = function innercode(i) {
        var a = i;
 var b = a;

        (function (d) {
  //codes
        }(document));
    }

    divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName;
    divElm.appendChild(scpt);
    headtg.appendChild(divElm);
    scpt.innerHTML = myfunc;
```

But the output coming up as

```html
<div class="abcd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function innercode(zID){var a = "10";var b = "20";;
    (function(d) {
            //lines of code of the function
        }(document));
    </script>
</div>
```

But I want the output to be like,

```html
<div class="abcd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 var a = "10";
        var b = "20";;
        (function(d) {
            //lines of code of the function
        }(document));
    </script>
</div>
```

Please advise

Comment: what do you want to do exactly ????!!!!!!!

Comment: 1. Go read [ask], and learn how to ask properly. Saying that you tried stuff without showing what you actually tried is nonsense. 2. Learn to do some basic research. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/adding-script-element-to-the-dom-and-have-the-javascript-run

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could just get the div element you want the code to be in, and then set the innerhtml to `<script>your code here</script>`

EDIT:
Try assigning your function like so:

```
var myFunc = function() {
    //Code
}
```

Then you can call myFunc(parameters)

Comment: tried but it is showing undefined within the script block

Comment: Well if the problems is that the function doesn't work, try creating it like in my edit.

Comment: I am using below codes.
 
    var myfunc = function innercode(i) {
        var a = i;
 var b = a;

        (function (d) {
  //codes
        }(document));
    }

    divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName;
    divElm.appendChild(scpt);
    headtg.appendChild(divElm);
    scpt.innerHTML = myfunc;
But the output coming up as 
<div class="abcd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function innercode(zID){var a = "10";var b = "20";;
(function(d) {
            //lines of code of the function
        }(document));
    </script>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this :

```
<html>
  <head>
      <script>
         var a = "10";
         var b = "20";

         function //here write you function name(d) {
        //lines of code of the function
          };
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Or you can write at this way :

```
<html>
<body onload='write your javascript code here'>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope it will work.let me know.

Comment: I am using below codes.
 
    var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var divElm = document.createElement('div');
    var scpt = document.createElement('script');
    scpt.type = 'text/javascript';
    var clName= "TEST";
    divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName;
    divElm.appendChild(scpt);
    headtg.appendChild(divElm);

But not sure how to add the below part in the script code,
    function innercode(i) {
        var a = i;
 var b = a;

        (function (d) {
  //codes
        }(document));
  }

Comment: in comment i cant read your code!update your question

Comment: updated the details in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**i understand from you comment on my persevios answer** you want to writer this code :

```
var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
var divElm = document.createElement('div');
var scpt = document.createElement('script');
scpt.type = 'text/javascript';
var clName= "TEST";
divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName; divElm.appendChild(scpt);
headtg.appendChild(divElm);

function innercode(i) {
  var a = i; var b = a;
}
function (d) {
   //codes }(document));
 }
```

if it is true you can write like this :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" >
        var headtg = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; 
        var divElm = document.createElement('div');
        var scpt = document.createElement('script');
        scpt.type = 'text/javascript';
        var clName= "TEST";
        divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName; divElm.appendChild(scpt);
        headtg.appendChild(divElm);

        function innercode(i) {
         var a = i; var b = a;
        }
        function (d) {
         //codes }(document));
          } 
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

i hope it will work.let me know

Comment: I am using below codes.
 
    var myfunc = function innercode(i) {
        var a = i;
 var b = a;

        (function (d) {
  //codes
        }(document));
    }

    divElm.className = "ABC_" + clName;
    divElm.appendChild(scpt);
    headtg.appendChild(divElm);
    scpt.innerHTML = myfunc;

But the output coming up as 

<div class="abcd">
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function innercode(zID){var a = "10";var b = "20";;
(function(d) {
            //lines of code of the function
        }(document));
    </script>
</div>

Comment: You should put <script> taq in head.not body!

Comment: I have added the script tag in the head only... Could not paste the entire code as the comment section is not allowing to do so

Comment: Update your question.(frok edit part)