# Is it possible to change DOM loaded javascript code without page load on the click of any button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for an approach where we can change DOM loaded javascript code on the click of button without page load.
Steps to reproduce:
Load a page and inspect
we have script tag where we have some code.
Now on the click of any button on the page wanted to change script code which i can see in inspect area but without page load.

As per below comment, we dont wanted to create script tag only.

First wanted to take existing DOM loaded script tag value, and update partial values under the script tag.
then removal of existing script tag and finally create new script tag - when user click on button

thanks for the comment

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't sound possible. I also cannot think of a use case for this.

Comment: Your question sounds a lot like this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/how-to-add-a-script-element-to-the-dom-and-execute-its-code

Comment: Delete the script tag, reset all the variables created by that script, create new script tag and append it to DOM