# Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined I am having trouble with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

thanks for reading.

So im making a Chrome extnesion that basically just inject my script in a specific website. It worked for a bit the just stoppped working and threw me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined.
The code and full project is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/ZeWhiteHatHacker/particle-clicker-hack).

So here is the JavaScript file that runs on particle clicker:

```js
console.log("Chrome Extension Hack loaded. Subscribe if you see this: https://bit. ly/BayMaxYT")
alert("Hack loaded! Coded by BayMax YT");
alert("Please subscribe! Gaming gear giveaways every 50 subscribers! https://bit. ly/BayMaxYT");

window.open("https://bit. ly/BayMaxYT");

// Main Hack Code for http://particle-clicker.web.cern.ch/particle-clicker/ By BayMax YT https://bit. ly/BayMaxYT 


(function(angular) {
  var e = angular.element;

  function c() {
    e('#detector').scope().dc.click();
  }

  function u() {
    var rcScope = e('#researchContent').scope().rc;
    rcScope.research.forEach(function(r) {
      if (rcScope.isAvailable(r)) {
        rcScope.doResearch(r);
      }
    });

    var hrScope = e('#hrContent').scope().hrc;
    hrScope.workers.forEach(function(w) {
      if (hrScope.isAvailable(w)) {
        hrScope.hire(w);
      }
    });

    var ucScope = e('#upgradesContent').scope().uc;
    ucScope.upgrades.forEach(function(u) {
      if (ucScope.isAvailable(u)) {
        ucScope.upgrade(u);
      }
    });
  }

  setInterval(c, 10);
  setInterval(u, 100);
})(angular);
```

And the MANIFEST is here:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "⚠ BETA ⚠ Particle Clicker Hack by BayMaxYT",
    "version": "0.2",
    "description": "desc123 123 hello",
    "icons": { "16": "/assets/icons/icon16.png",
                "48": "/assets/icons/icon48.png",
                "128": "/assets/icons/icon128.png" },
    "author": "BayMax YT https://bit. ly/BayMaxYT",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "background"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "http://particle-clicker.web.cern.ch/particle-clicker/"
            ],
            "js": ["js/main.js"]
        }
    ],

    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "html/popup.html",
        "default_title": "A popup here soon"
    }
}
```

I had to dismantle the links but you don't need to click them; they just open up me channel ^^ dont ban me pls

Comment: To use angular you need to load its script first or compile to a bundle as shown in various tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome content scripts function in an [isolated scope](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#isolated_world), meaning you can't access the angular variable the way you're trying.

However, there is a workaround for it.  Instead of injecting your code using a content script, use the content script [create a script element with your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/how-to-add-a-script-element-to-the-dom-and-execute-its-code) and add it to the page.

Comment: Thanks for your rather quick reply, but the thing is: If I copy all my code from my main.js (wich is my content script) and paste it in the chrome devtools console, it works just fine.

Comment: Right - because when you've done that, you've injected it directly into the scope of the page.  Content scripts don't function the same way.

Comment: but it worked with me not changing ANYTHING related to "angular" or variable or the script file or the manifest content script zone?

Comment: The code posted in the question and linked in github could not have worked. Never. If it did, then either something was different in the code or you encountered a super massive security bug in the browser which got fixed, naturally. I'm not aware of any such recent bugs though.