# How can I add a minified js script to the dom and execute it?

Tags: javascript

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/how-to-add-a-script-element-to-the-dom-and-execute-its-code). The difference is that I am trying to add a minified js code in the script tag. If I type some simple code, it works. For example, run this on a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/):

```
var s = document.createElement( 'script' );
var code = `
        console.log("success");
        `;
    
    try {
      s.appendChild(document.createTextNode(code));
      document.head.appendChild(s);
    } catch (e) {
      s.text = code;
      document.head.appendChild(s);
    }
```

However, try replacing the `console.log("success");` with the contents from this [link](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.3.2/html2canvas.min.js).

You will get the error `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"`. Which is weird because...if I add the script using the source attribute and url of the file, it works. I don't understand why adding the contents directly fails.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I make it work? Thank you for your time.

Here is the jsfiddle with the [non-working code](http://jsfiddle.net/yn9f374d)

Comment: Share your code for adding the code with the link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yn9f374d/ . I literally just copy pasted the contents from the minified js file, nothing special.

Comment: help ;_;. I can't find anything on google.

Comment: This isn't a good idea. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Because I don't want to have to download the library dynamically, because of the chance of failure(cdn is down, repo doesn't exist anymore, etc). I solved the problem by simply having the file as a .js and using the source attribute. So instead of the source being a remote url, it's local. Problem solved. I am still curious why copy pasting doesn't work though.

Comment: If I manually add the script tag with the contents of the minified js, it works fyi. It doesn't work only if I try to do it with code. Go figure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a <script> element to the DOM and execute its code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432984/how-to-add-a-script-element-to-the-dom-and-execute-its-code)

Comment: First, why can't you do it normally with a link to the local file? Also, a CDN exists for a purpose. If it was unreliable, nobody would use it. There is basically a 0% chance that it would go down, and if it does, your site would probably go down too. A CDN has more fail-resistance and a much higher uptime unless spend over a million dollars in hosting. Also, the files will exist forever, and the repo will never get deleted.

Comment: In my question I already linked to that SO post. It doesn't work. And I already said that I am linking to a local file.

My point is why it doesn't work? That's what I want to know. I know there are alternatives, but I am interested in knowing why what I want to do fails.

Comment: For whoever closed my question....please read my post carefully. I literally say in my post that the similar question doesn't solve the problem! I know there are alternatives...what I want to understand is why my original approach doesn't work!

Comment: Your question probably got closed because it was not explained properly. Your use case was very nonstandard and wasn't good. I understand that you want to know why it isn't working, but think of it this way: Would you spend your valuable time fixing some theoretical problem someone has if it will not help ANYBODY to fix?

Comment: How are you actually "*replacing the console.log("success"); with the contents from this link*"? What you need to provide is the not working code.

Comment: @RobG I did provide it...here jsfiddle.net/yn9f374d ...

Comment: @Shivam I understand your point. I thought it was an interesting problem. Knowledge is knowledge anyways. You know like, it bothers me not knowing why it doesn't work. Maybe someone will find it curious as well and investigate? I don't know man I don't think this is a useless question just because there are other viable alternatives, but to each his own.

Comment: @savram—thanks for adding the actual code. Adding a large slab of minified code as a text template is fraught as if the text contains the start sequence for an expression "${" or template delimiter "\`" you'll get an error. However, that doesn't seem to be the issue here. I get an "unexpected EOF" error, so perhaps it's taking too long to insert the +200kB of code into the text node so that execution is attempted before the code has finished being inserted.