# Any way to stop JQuery eating my <script> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have inline javascript within my HTML. Each individual component that requires animation or action (sliders, expanding text areas, etc.) each have their own inline script, that sets up the animation and such for that individual component.

The way i have it set up, Each script is position dependent: it references its own position in the DOM, and traverses it to find the component it wants to manipulate (e.g. "add onclick to the parent div"). This is normally an incredibly bad idea for several reasons:

- having to repeat the same code all over the place, losing DRY
- being very verbose, repeating the same chunk of text over and over, taking up bandwidth
- cluttering up your HTML with a bunch of inline scripts, making it hard to read

However, the second problem is easily solved with GZIP, and i have solved the first and last problem.

This has the advantage of locality of reference: the component and the scripts they require are kept in one place, not spread out over separate files. Also, I isolate each set of scripts in a (function(){})(), and avoid polluting the global namespace, so each set of scripts for each component is written once and doesn't interact with scripts written elsewhere at all. Perfect modularity

So the question is, how can i stop JQuery eating my script tags when i do Ajax DOM insertions/replacements? If it didn't eat my scripts, because each component is completely self-contained with it's own scripts, i can simply run every script tag in the new component's DOM and that would be that; everything will be set up. No more fiddling with decided which global scripts need to be re-run depending on which component changed.

However, since JQuery seems to insist on stripping my script tags and moving them somewhere, this no longer works. I could do the insertion by modifying replacing the HTML of the entire document, but that causes the whole screen to flash as it reflows (among other problems). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but your overall approach is not a good one, for many reasons (your question here being one of them).

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you; in this demo, the script tags appear to still be in the same place: http://jsfiddle.net/xMFKn/ However, if you are writing directly to the DOM as you load the page, this may be the problem with rerunning your scripts again after page load.

Comment: [The reason for the disappearing script tags is explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element/3603496#3603496).

Comment: @Pointy: I am aware that this approach is not a good approach in any existing paradigm. However, i have written my own framework, so i can literally have whatever mapping i want between the source code i write and the html that gets output. I think that, abstractly, having the scripts be self contained to each component is a valuable thing. It is utterly insane in any other language to write programs as a whole bunch of overlapping global functions operating on a set of global variables. I want to see if i can make this paradigm work.

Comment: How sure are you that GZIP "solves" the second problem?

Comment: Can you set up a jsFiddle or other demo? Jared's demo doesn't strip `<script>` tags.

Comment: @nnnnnn: not very sure, but pretty sure, if my understanding of compression and information theory is correct. Anyway, the point of this is that I'm experimenting with the way I have my separation of concerns and information placement within the code. Trying to start squeezing for minimal bandwidth or maximal performance would be a premature optimization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about jQuery explicitly, but most libraries will remove script elements from content returned from XHR that they intend to insert using innerHTML. That is because inserting innerHTML does not execute the scripts (in the vast majority of browsers). Looking at the jQuery source, the *load* method strips out script elements.

So they strip out the script elements, then insert the HTML. This ensures the scripts aren't executed or cause issues.

Some libraries have an "execute script" (or similar) flag that, if set, means they will pass the script element content to *eval*, but there are pitfalls with that too.

One solution is to put all your script snippets into separate files, then use a src attribute on the script elements. If you can't find a jQuery method that doesn't remove the scripts, it's pretty simple to write your own "get" or "load" or whatever function that doesn't, or use one of the thousands that are already written.

If you are only using script elements, you can simply create a script element, set the *src* attribute and put it in the DOM (this is one method of doing AJAX).

Answer (score 0):

in your html keep spaces for all the replacements using container divs, so that everything you're replacing through AJAX has a special place in the DOM. jQuery wont eat your script tag.

Alternatively, you can also put an id on your script tags and then access then by using the ids.

Comment: Actually jQuery definitely does actively and explicitly remove `<script>` blocks from content fetched via things like ".load()".