# <script> tags in ajax response not being parsed by IE <= 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, script-tag

I have a page that uses jQuery's $.post() method to get some html and inside the html is a  tag.

My code looks something like this:

```
$.post( 'myUrl',
    { someData : 'someData', moreData : 'moreData'},
    function(response){
        $('body').append(response);
});
```

Is there a reason that the script tag will not parse in IE <= 8?  It parses just fine in every other browser.  I've been searching around on the web for a few hours now and can't seem to find anything on this issue so I'm assuming I'm forgetting something or flat out doing something wrong?

EDIT:

Just found this on the jQuery site ( http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) regarding the html dataType for ajax requests:

"Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM."

On a related SO question ( [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element) ): The answer given by @Hendra states this SHOULD be working.  Which still leaves me wondoring why this doesn't work in IE7/8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

My site uses html5 and thus relies on innershiv ( http://jdbartlett.com/innershiv/ ) for inserting elements into the dom for non-html5 browsers (for me this would be ie7/8)

I had forgotten that we have an automated script that calls innershiv on all jQuery insertion methods ( .html(), .append(), etc..)

The reason this was failing for me is that innershiv was circumventing jQuery's script evaluation.

The fix was to do the script evaluation from within the script that calls innershiv.  JD Bartlett provides a more detailed explanation here:  https://github.com/jdbartlett/innershiv/issues/4

Answer (score 1):

Using DOM methods to insert a `<script>` tag results in the tag being executed. Just using `innerHTML` (or some framework that uses it) will NOT result in the script being executed. This is probably the cause of your problem. I suggest separating the HTML and JS, then running `eval` on the JS section.

Comment: Thanks.  I did as you suggested.  I searched for the js and ran eval and it worked in IE.  However, for all other browsers that were already working they now parse the <script> tags twice.  There must be a better solution?

Comment: Well, if you've already parsed to find the scripts, you can easily remove them, right? Do that, and everything should fall into place.

Comment: that makes sense but jQuery claims to do this for us already...any idea why it's failing in IE7/8 and working everywhere else (including IE9) - see my edit in the question as well as the link I provided in the question's comments.  I just want to make sure I'm not overlooking a potential problem somewhere else.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't really help much more on this. I am firmly against using jQuery (I think it's ugly and for lazy programmers), and I write my code myself - that way it actually works and I can debug effectively if needed.