# Append script to body, using Chrome user script

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I want to add a script to a given page with a Greasemonkey style user script in Chrome.

I use this [trick](http://erikvold.com/blog/index.cfm/2010/6/14/using-jquery-with-a-user-script) to add jQuery to my user script.

If I try to add i.e. `<h1>Test</h1>` to a pages body with jQuery's append-method, everything works fine.

However if I try to append a JS-script nothing happens.

How do I troubleshoot a problem like this?

This is my .user.js-file:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @match http://*/*
// ==/UserScript==

// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://timkl.com/wip/bibobRedesign/js/jquery.contenthack.js"></script>');
});

}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery handles script elements differently than other DOM elements.  There is additional detail in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/181776).

To append your script the safest way would be to use the same method that is used to insert the jQuery library.

```
function main() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://timkl.com/wip/bibobRedesign/js/jquery.contenthack.js");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$('body').append();
    });
}
```

**Untested Option**
If you have *lots* of scripts to load take a look at a script loader (such as [LABjs](http://labjs.com/))

You *might* be able to do something like the following:

```
function addLABjs(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("src", "http://somepath.to/LAB.js");
    script.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.textContent = "(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }, false);
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript


function main() {
    $LAB.script("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js").wait()
        .script("http://timkl.com/wip/bibobRedesign/js/jquery.contenthack.js")
        .script("YourOtherScript.js").wait();

    $(document).ready(function () {
    });
}

addLABjs(main);
```