# Using jQuery, how can I limit my number of ad units based on page height?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My app is built using a 2-column design, with the right 300-pixel column being used to show **one** Adsense ad unit.

Since some pages are taller, I am wondering if there's a way to have jQuery determine the height of my `#main_wrapper` and show **an additional ad unit** if it exceeds a certain size in pixels. Sort of like this:

```
    // ad unit #1 shown here by default in all pages

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

            if ($('#main_wrapper').height() > 660) {

            //show add unit #2
        }

});

</script>
```

My issue is with how to deal with wrapping the ad unit code with the jQuery/JS condition above. A typical ad unit is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-123123123123";
/* Sidebar 300 Middle */
google_ad_slot = "123123123";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

How would I insert that inside the jQuery above?

Comment: Could you not clone the existing script block(s) relevant to ads, and simply append them in the newly added ad-components?

Comment: @david, not sure I understand how to do that - sorry - could you post an example?

Comment: I'd love to, but I've not used Google's AdSense, so I don't know which of the two `script` blocks you'd need to add/duplicate/clone *or* to where you'd need to append them. My previous comment was a suggestion, of sorts, but without actual knowledge to back it up.

Comment: thx - actually both script blocks are needed for an ad to display - even if you're showing more than one - each has to have 2 script blocks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should include this strings in the needed block?

```
 if ($('#main_wrapper').height() > 660)
 {
  google_ad_client = "ca-pub-123123123123";
  google_ad_slot = "123123123";
  google_ad_width = 300;
  google_ad_height = 250;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

**Edit:** Code changed as previous was causing error parsing `</script>`

**Edit:** After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/1114171) replaced jquery's `.append()` with pojs and script element is being added to DOM tree

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    function adUnit(client, slot, width, height) {
        var unit = '<!--\n';
            unit += 'google_ad_client = ' + client + ';\n';
            unit += 'google_ad_slot = ' + slot + ';\n';
            unit += 'google_ad_width = ' + width + ';\n';
            unit += 'google_ad_height = ' + height + ';\n';
            unit += '//-->';

        var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.text =  unit;

        document.head.appendChild(script);
        console.log('adUnit executed');
    }
    adUnit(1, 2, 3, 4);

});
```

Comment: tom i get unterminated string literal error on firebug - do you know if some chars need to be escaped?

Comment: seems like it didn't like `</script>` have taken a slightly different approach though it doesn't seem to appear in the element inspector in chrome will investigate :-)

Comment: thx tom - this seems trickier than i thought - the new code throws an error that i can't locate - it says "ca is not defined"

Comment: i also think that the second script block needs to be next to the first, cannot be added to <head>