# How to include an embedded youtube channel in a page after document.ready?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, youtube, youtube-api

i have a youtube embedded channel from a certain company, and below i have a list of links to other related companies, however this is just a widget on my page, so when i click a link in the list i want to get the new embedded youtube channel from the other company with an ajax call. i've tried running the script that i got from the youtube api but it does not load, i've also tried putting the script inside a div and then inserting the div in the widget and still no luck. does anyone have an idea how i can do this?

so this is the script i got from youtube for embedding a channel:

```
  <div style="padding-bottom:10px" id="divYoutubeTab">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://www.google.com/ig/modules/youtube.xml&up_channel=opelblog&synd=open&w=880&h=390&title=&border=%23ffffff%7C3px%2C1px+solid+%23999999&output=js"></script>

</div>
```

i would like to click a link and on the onclick function i just change the channel name and the channel should reload to the new channel .. but i can't. the ajax call is just to get the name of the channel from my database

Comment: Please, don't put your code in comments - edit your question and put it inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at the following projects:

- [jquery Youtoube Channel Plugin](https://github.com/dharyk/jQuery.youtubeChannel)
- [jquery Youtoube Channel Playlist](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ChannelPlaylist)

Answer (score 0):

[I had a go myself](http://jsfiddle.net/NJ2JN/2/) on jsfiddle and its obviously an issue with introducing script after the page has loaded.

While I could not create a solution myself...

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element) may be the answer you are looking for