# How in insert dynamic JavaScript tag into iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

**FINAL UPDATE: The second code block is working--I just miss-typed the URL.**

I'm trying to place a dynamically created script into an iframe. I can access the head of the iframe, but it doesn't seem to accept the append request. The console log call returns the head tag, and the following append of text into the body works fine. I've also tried appending the script tag to the body. (note: the script tag is not on the same domain, so I've avoided using getScript or ajax).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<iframe></iframe>', {
      name:"contentFrame"
      ,id:"contentFrame"
  }).css("height", 300).css("width", 500).load(function() {
      var script   = document.createElement("script");
      script.type  = "text/javascript";
      script.src   = "//cross-domain.com/script.js";
      console.log($(this).contents().find("head")); // outputs: [<head></head>]
      $(this).contents().find("head").append(script); // doesn't work
      $(this).contents().find("body").append(script); // doesn't work
      $(this).contents().find("body").append("Test"); // works
  }).appendTo("#content");
});
```

Here is the new version that successfully appends the script based upon the suggestion below, but the script doesn't evaluate (as tested by a simple alert). Plus, another oddity: the "working" icon displays for about 15 seconds and the status (in chrome) says "retrieving..." Eventually it stops, but nothing happens.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $('<iframe></iframe>', {
      name:"contentFrame"
      ,id:"contentFrame"
  }).css("height", 300).css("width", 500).load(function() {
      var script   = document.createElement("script");
      script.type  = "text/javascript";
      script.src   = "//cross-domain.com/script.js";
      console.log($(this).contents().find("head"));
      $(this).contents().find("head")[0].appendChild(script);
      $(this).contents().find("body").append("Test");
  }).appendTo("#content");
});
```

Update: When the cursor icon finally finishes working (about 10 seconds, which is odd because it's a local server with one line of code), I get this message in the Chrome console (it's in all red with a red circle "X" icon next to it):

```
GET http://cross-domain.com/script.js 
(anonymous function)temp.html:16
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-1.7.1.js:3261
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandlejquery-1.7.1.js:2880
jQuery.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.7.1.js:5771
jQuery.fn.extend.domManipjquery-1.7.1.js:5973
jQuery.fn.extend.appendjquery-1.7.1.js:5769
jQuery.each.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)jquery-1.7.1.js:6162
(anonymous function)temp.html:18
jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery-1.7.1.js:1049
jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery-1.7.1.js:1167
jQuery.extend.readyjquery-1.7.1.js:435
DOMContentLoaded
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/220299

It may in fact be working, but the script tag is just not visible.

Comment: So the take-away is that you cannot use the JQuery "append", but using  traditional scripting methods will work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('<iframe></iframe>', {
      name:"contentFrame"
      ,id:"contentFrame"
  }).css("height", 300).css("width", 500).load(function() {
      $(this).contents().find("head").append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="//cross-domain.com/script.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  }).appendTo("#content");
});
```