# Error can't add file javascript on <head> tag

Tags: jquery

I have a sample code:

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
     $('head').append('<link href="\"style.css\"" rel="\"stylesheet\"" type="\"text/css\"">');
     $('head').append('<script src="\"click.js\"" type="\"text/javascript\""></script>');
});
```

This code only add file css on head, can't add click.js on head, how to fix

Comment: you shouldn't have to escape the double quotes if it is in single quotes. try removing all those escape characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Comment: gonna guess that that's in an HTML file and that `</script>` is ending the script element. use `<\/script>` instead. Alternatively, post more code so that we can see where it's getting called.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to load and execute the script, you can do this:

```
$.getScript("click.js");
```

I don't see why you need it in the head.

Answer (score 0):

From the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
$("#someElement").append(script);
```

Please search question on SO, and if you don't find any answer, then post new question.

Hope this solution works for you.