# Load javascript after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an external javascript that contains something like:

```
document.writeln("<script type='text/javascript' src='...'></script>");
```

In the original html i have something link

```
<div id="banner">
    <script type="text/javscript" src="<the external javascript above>"></script> 
</div>
```

How can i load that delayed?

I've tried using window.setTimeout and append that javascript but its not working.

Its important that the javascript to be loaded inside that div so the document.writeln executes in the right place.

Thank you.

Comment: Try the answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Comment: @bukko - i've tried that but no luck. The writeln its not executed in same div.

Comment: Strange - I posted as an answer but it comes up as a comment :/

Answer (score 2):

You can call your injection code on window.onload.

```
window.onload = function() {  
  inject();  
  doSomethingElse();  
};
```

window.onload will wait until all assets have finished downloading, such as images and scripts. After scripts are downloaded, you can inject your code to page.

Comment: I know how to execute after the page was loaded, i want to be executed correctly. The JavaScript its not executed in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a better way to do it would be to add a delay to the script.
Also, if you use something other than 'document.writeln' for example:

```
$('#banner').append(...);
```

you can better direct where it goes.

Comment: Read the question again and you will see i already tried that

Comment: Can you show the code you tried? I use those all the time and they work fine.

Comment: Also, what is the script doing? Does it really need to execute within the div? You can manipulate elements from anywhere within your document, and ideally scripts should stay in the header.

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source javascript library for doing this kind of thing: http://labjs.com/

I have used it in the past and it worked very well.

Answer (score 0):

> Its important that the javascript to be loaded inside that div so the document.writeln executes in the right place.

That is not entirely true. Especially if the div is empty you could simply use: `document.getElementById('banner').innerHTML = "<h1>HTML-Output here.</h1>"`

[Bukko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218548/bukko)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174428/1173897) would work as well if you are using jQuery. My answer is pure Javascript. With this newfound freedom you should be able to simply put the loading of your script at the bottom of the page or use a custom body.onload() function
Edit: or simply follow [Samet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/323659/samet-atdag)'s [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9174339/1173897) in conjunction with the .innerHTML. Hope this helps.