# A script that is executed only if I don't append it by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, social-networking

This is my code :

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script><script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,type: "profile",rpp: 4,interval: 30000,width: 650,height: 202,theme: {shell: {background: "#7ee1fc",color: "#2e2e2e"},tweets: {background: "#ffffff",color: "#949494",links: "#009ece"}},features: {scrollbar: true,loop: false,vlive: false,hashtags: true,timestamp: true,avatars: false,behavior: "all"}}).render().setUser("microsoft").start();</script>
```

which load a twitter plugins (but this, in fact, doesnt matter). Well, now, If I wrote the whole code in a "string" and I append it by jQuery :

```
var myText='<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"><\/script><script>new TWTR.Widget({version: 2,type: "profile",rpp: 4,interval: 30000,width: 650,height: 202,theme: {shell: {background: "#7ee1fc",color: "#2e2e2e"},tweets: {background: "#ffffff",color: "#949494",links: "#009ece"}},features: {scrollbar: true,loop: false,vlive: false,hashtags: true,timestamp: true,avatars: false,behavior: "all"}}).render().setUser("microsoft").start();<\/script>'

$('#twitterContent').html(myText);
```

seems that it **can't** load it (I get an error, *TWTR is not defined*).

So why one version should works and the other one not? And how can I fix this trouble?

P.S. If you want test code, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dRZnn/2/) is the fiddle.

Comment: `<\/script>` ? I don't think you need to escape those in a string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Comment: @elclanrs: this is required -- the browser's parser would otherwise treat it as the end of `<script>` tag... the one that contains the JavaScript code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery version:

```
$.getScript("http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js", function() {
new TWTR.Widget({id: 'twitterContent',version: 2,type: "profile",rpp: 4,interval: 30000,width: 650,height: 202,theme: {shell: {background: "#7ee1fc",color: "#2e2e2e"},tweets: {background: "#ffffff",color: "#949494",links: "#009ece"}},features: {scrollbar: true,loop: false,vlive: false,hashtags: true,timestamp: true,avatars: false,behavior: "all"}}).render().setUser("microsoft").start();
})​;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dRZnn/4/)

Comment: I was writing exactly the same code but were faster. Congrat! :)

Comment: I'm getting this weird result where your JSFiddle is constantly erroring `attempt to run compile-and-go script on a cleared scope`. Is this the desired effect?

Comment: @Marc is'nt that annoying. Been there, more than once!

Comment: This will clear the document content and replace every thing with the twitter content!

Comment: @ShadowScripter - Nope, that was not the desired effect, it's working just fine here, and I don't seem to be able to reproduce anything like that in JSFiddle? Can't think of any reasons why it shouldn't work either.

Comment: @SalmanA - edited my answer, just missing an attribute in the OP's code (the id attribute to render to).

Comment: @adeno: right, I was looking for documentation searching for ways to _attach to element_ instead of document.write. Your example now seems to work.

Comment: @SalmanA - It's a twitter problem, all such widgets needs to have an ID passed, or it will just write to whatever element it is inside, wich when done in an external script will be the document. Also, wrapping it in a window.onload or using a timeout to defer it will keep it from blocking the site load, wich usually is the way to go as this social media crap tends to load way to slow for most sites.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need another way to insert script element

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = url;
script.text = ".............";
$("#twitterContent").append( script );
```