# Add Javascript into a DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Have any advice. Why I can not add the javascript into a DOM?

```
var strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'></script>";
$("#someElement").append(strScript);
```

Comment: It doesn't do much, but that works just fine in my browser (using `body` instead of `#someElement`).

Comment: Why are you trying to append a script tag into the DOM instead of simply calling a function when you want something to be executed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Comment: ok. Thank all. now I have found the answer... Cheer !!!

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element) post.  The top-rated comment does a stand-up job of going through what works and why.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do

```
document.write('\x3Cscript src="your-jsfile.js" type="text/javascript" >\x3C/script>');
```

Comment: use `document.body.innerHMTL += str` instead of `document.write( str );document.close();`