# How to insert tracking code in prettyPhoto image view (lightbox)?

Tags: jquery, append, prettyphoto

I know that similar questions have been asked regarding google analytics, but in this case, the tracking code is a bit more complex.
I want to append the tracking code to each image viewed via prettyPhoto.

In the prettyPhoto init method I define the changepicturecallback to call a function: myCallbaclFunc:

```
$(".gallery:first a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
            animation_speed:'normal',
            theme:'light_square',
            slideshow:3000, 
            autoplay_slideshow: false, 
            show_title: true, 
            overlay_gallery_max: 3000,
            changepicturecallback: myCallbackFunc
            });
```

then, myCallbackFunc is defined as:

```
myCallbackFunc = function() {
//append code to social container div
$('.pp_social').append('<div class="netscope"><script type="text/javascript">var WRP_ID=316817;var WRP_SECTION="COMUNIDADE";var WRP_SUBSECTION="Estudos MensHealth";var WRP_SECTION_GRP="316817 - MensHealth";var WRP_SUBSECTION_GRP= WRP_SECTION;var WRP_CONTENT="Home content";var WRP_CHANNEL;var WRP_ACC;wreport_ok=0;</scr'+'ipt><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.autohoje.com/inc/netscope2.js"></scr'+'ipt><script type="text/javascript">if(wreport_ok==1){ var w_counter = new wreport_counter(WRP_SECTION, WRP_SUBSECTION, WRP_ID, WRP_ACC, WRP_CHANNEL, WRP_SECTION_GRP, WRP_SUBSECTION_GRP);w_counter.add_content(WRP_CONTENT);w_counter.count();}</scr'+'ipt></div>');
```

}

But all I get as I inspect the generated code is the emtpy div class="netscope"

Is there other method than "append" I should be using? 
Should I somehow escape the javascript code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: language tag is not really recommended, use `type='text/javascript'`

Comment: It's loading fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/wzzGA/ You have to look in the `script` tag for the Javascript source.

Comment: @Jared - If I inspect the result section all I can see is the created div. The append works fine for that. But the javascript code doesn't show inside the div

Comment: Your scripts are there; it doesn't matter if they're "in" that `div` or not. Try: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/wzzGA/1/ You'll see one of the variables you declare prints. Look at the `Script` tab in Firebug and you'll see the scripts are there, they're just now showing in the HTML tab as elements.

Comment: Thanks Jared. I believe your are right :)

Answer (score 0):

[Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

May be you are in browser that has this issue.

Or it can be the issue by which you dont see it in DOM,

See @Hendra Uzia s answer refering to the issue,

> All of jQuery's insertion methods use a domManip function internally
>   to clean/process elements before and after they are inserted into the
>   DOM. One of the things the domManip function does is pull out any
>   script elements about to be inserted and run them through an
>   "evalScript routine" rather than inject them with the rest of the DOM
>   fragment. It inserts the scripts separately, evaluates them, and then
>   removes them from the DOM.
>
> I believe that one of the reasons jQuery does this is to avoid
>   "Permission Denied" errors that can occur in Internet Explorer when
>   inserting scripts under certain circumstances. It also avoids
>   repeatedly inserting/evaluating the same script (which could
>   potentially cause problems) if it is within a containing element that
>   you are inserting and then moving around the DOM.
>
> My understanding of the intricacies of script injection is pretty
>   limited, so if you'd like to discuss it further, maybe you could post
>   a topic on the jQuery forum.