# document.createElement('script').src = variable? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is it possible to create something that similar to:

```
var jsfile = "code....";
(a=(b=document).createElement('script')).src=jsfile;
b.body.appendChild(a);
```

where 'jsfile' is like an external js file but in our case will be a variable?

All of my tests failed and I succeeded to get the input of 'jsfile' but if there were function inside of obj (remember I want it to preform like an external js file) they didn't executed.

Example for a test:

```
var jsfile = "code....";
(a=(b=document).createElement('script')).text=(jsfile);
b.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're asking. I really can't tell. I see no problem in your code.

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Answer (score 9):

Try setting a type on the script element, like so (taken from [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)):

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "path/to/your/javascript.js";    // use this for linked script
script.text  = "alert('voila!');"               // use this for inline script
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can, actually, the `src` attribute is used only for a javascript file path, if you want to render the code you can use the `innerText` property:

```
var code = 'alert("working!")';
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.innerText = code;

document.body.appendChild(script);
```