# jquery append script to html element dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to dynamically add more items (videos. which is in script form) to div. In below code, append doesn't do anything. I have tried to append script in string form too (i.e. ""). I appreciate any help!!!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://video.foxnews.com/v/embed.js?id=1993203907001&w=466&h=263"></script>
  </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://video.foxnews.com/v/embed.js?id=1993203907001&w=466&h=263';
  $("div").append(script);
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: usually I always  ad an id to a div like <div id="mydiv"> and then use $("mydiv").append(script)

Comment: @Terradon - it shouldn't make any difference. anyways I also do that In my code :)

Comment: It has to do with the way you're defining your `var script`. I would suggest attempting to append the html script tag as a string, and share your results here.

Comment: Is this your real script?? because you add the same video you already have in your div??

Comment: ideally I pull down new video dynamically and add it. this is to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///C:/Users/###/Desktop/test.html from frame with URL http://video.foxnews.com/v/video-embed.html?video_id=1993203907001&w=466&h=263&loc=. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Your trying to access something from a different domain => XSS

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

and also

https://support.ookla.com/entries/21097566-what-is-crossdomain-xml-and-why-do-i-need-it

Comment: thanks for respond. If you copy/paste my code in notepad and save as .html, you will see that it can embed video. but ideally it should have two videos.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery handles `<script />` tags in a special way ([.append()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.fn.append) -> [.domManip()](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.8.0/jQuery.fn.domManip))
Just use the DOM method `.appendChild()` instead

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(script);​
```

Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/402037) for a deeper look into the *why*?

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing this line

```
$("div").append(script);
```

with this

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].appendChild(script);​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/hLcVC/1/)**

The native `.appendChild` method seems to be working , but the 
jQuery `.append()` does not seem to be working for some reason..

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Why you think its irrelevant? It addresses the problem (just missing an explanation)

Comment: @Sushanth - It doesn't address the problem. are you able to see video in fiddle? it should embed video if it works.

Comment: I think that is another issue for which answer given by pensan might be in the right direction...

Comment: @Sushanth: It doesn't. jQuery handles scripts correctly. Check network tab just to make sure that script was actually loaded. Your solution adds nothing.