# Replace with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: Can’t append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

i am trying to replace a div with a javascript by doing this:

```
$("#frame").replaceWith("<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>AC_VHost_Embed(2672266,206,206,'',1,1, 2279587, 0,1,0,'912832a3e8b02d79380c8352f2d497f6',9);</script>") ;
```

But in console, error says Unexpected token: ILLEGAL

Any idea?

Comment: This might help you: [jquery-cant-append-script-element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing this is inlined JavaScript, in which case you need to break up your closing `</script>` tag. I also made it more readable:

```
$("#frame").replaceWith(
    "<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>"
    + "AC_VHost_Embed(2672266,206,206,'',1,1, 2279587, "
    + "0,1,0,'912832a3e8b02d79380c8352f2d497f6',9);"
    + "<" + "/script>"
);
```

The reason for this is so that the browser doesn't think that your `</script>` inside the string is the end of the script block.  Example:

```
<script>
    // Doesn't work!
    alert('</script>');
</script>
```

Your browser sees:

```
<script>
    // Doesn't work!
    alert('
</script>
');
</script>
```

In other words, your browser thinks the script ends the first time it sees `</script>`. You can fix this by breaking the fake `</script>` up into pieces.

```
<script>
    // Works fine!
    alert('<' + '/script>');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>Appending a script tag to the DOM after it is rendered will not automatically load the script.</s>

Have a look at this jQuery function to load scripts: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: Oh, you're right. Either way, getScript might be good to know about.