# Using JQuery, how could I add content (Another script) DIRECTLY before the </body> tag in a page?

Tags: jquery

Basically what I want to do is, using JQuery, add a script directly before the closing body tag on a page.

AKA

```
SCRIPT HERE
</body>
```

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: When, from where, and why are you trying to do this? i.e. are you trying to do this before the page loads, onload, or sometime after the page has fully loaded?

Answer (score 5):

use can use `$('body').append('<script></script')`

Update: [Looks like this maynot work always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element)

So Try

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.text  = "alert('voila!');"               // use this for inline script
script.src   = "path/to/your/javascript.js";    // use this for linked script

$('body').append(script)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CX5fm/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('<script>', { src: "path/to/script.js" }).appendTo("body");
```

Comment: Is this going to append right after the 
<body> 
tag or before the 
</body

Comment: This will add `script` tag before closing tag of `body`.

Answer (score 0):

firstly add a footer div right befor `</body>` like this `<div id="footer"></div>` then :

```
$('#footer').after('<script type="text/javascript">SCRIPT HERE</script>');
```