# Which jQuery commands to use for inserting script tag (that contains counter timer) inside html?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add the counter timer script, using jQuery. right after the id="counter" pargraph
so instead of this code:

```
<body>

<p> beginning of site</p>

<table id="timer_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="counter"  style="color: red;"> Here's the counter: </p>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p> rest of site...</p>

</body>
```

i'll get this code:

```
<body>

<p> beginning of site</p>

<table id="timer_table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p id="counter"  style="color: red;"> Here's the counter: </p>
                <script>
                    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316});
                </script>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p> rest of site...</p>

</body>
```

I do it by using the firebug console, I'm running this: (AS WRITTEN IN [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element),
tough, it STILL does NOT work well)

```
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
script.src   = "js_folder/js1.js";
$('#counter').after(script);
```

js1.js is simplly:

```
var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316});
```

It doesn't work well.
instead of getting this outcome:  http://bit.ly/19Ve9oM
I get this one: http://postimg.org/image/np8y4spbx/

And when i try to check the page source I get nothing.

To sum it up:
Which jquery commnad do should i use to insert the

```
                <script>
                    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316});
                </script>
```

right after the id="counter" paragraph? and that it would work as if the original html had this line already written in it

Thank you

Comment: Why not just put `var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316})` in a `.ready` handler?

Comment: @Ryan It might be a duplicate, but I don't really think it is what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Where a script is initialized should be of little importance, if the script is written properly. Most scripts should be loaded at the bottom of a page, to speed up the time it takes for the browser to render the DOM, since script tags are blocking unless they have the `async` attribute set to `true`.

To load a script with jQuery you use the [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method inside a [`jQuery.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ready/) handler to make sure that the code is not executed until the DOM is ready. In your case it would look like this:

```
// This is a shorthand for jQuery.ready
$(function(){
    $.getScript("js_folder/js1.js");
});
```

The above snippet should be added to a script tag at the bottom of the document (due to the reasons I've already stated), but will work from anywhere.

However, considering the content of `js_folder/js1.js` you should rather put that inside the `.ready` handler instead. Such as this:

```
$(function(){
    var myCountdown1 = new Countdown({time:316});
});
```

Comment: I thank you for your efforts,
I understand I wasn't clear enough. I'll ask again, differently.
And I did read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element before posting this question,
I mean.. I did do what was written there....
It does work for a simple script, like adding <p>hi</p>
But not for adding a countdown.