# How to run javascript in hidden header to include external file

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

How to run javascript in hidden header to include and run external javascript files?

Using

```
document.createElement('script');
var js = documemnt.getElementsByTags('head')[0];
js.src = "file.js"; // File location
js.type = text/javascript;
```

and

```
head.appendChild(js);
```

to add to head section.
I want to execute the javascript code in the similar way to add to head hidden behind to execute and `.removeChild()` to remove the code after code executed.
Please tell me how to execute the code on hidden head.

Edited// 
The example use `ScriptManager` , Referene:[public final class ClientScriptManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), to handle the client side scripts to hide javascript and run,
[Call to javascript Function from code behind using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/443131/Call-to-javascript-Function-from-code-behind-using).
 There is no reference of it also, but with asp.net. Please tell me how to use them only on javascript without asp.net, **"because it makes only slower to use asp without any commercial uses."**

Comment: What does "on hidden head" mean? What you have there will work just fine. (Side note: You don't need the `type` property, the default is and always has been JavaScript.)

Comment: As T.J. said, head section is hidden, on the other hand, scripts are not visible. Describe more about your question

Comment: I dare add to the above... sounds like the included file (js.src) is not found. What does firebug/developer tools' network tab show?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't append <script> element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)

Comment: I read that you can add the script element to the header behind and run with adding dynamically. Please tell me how to add them. "_This question may already have an answer here:
Can't append <script> element 11 answers_" It is not a duplicate contents because the question is not about the same subject. I am asking how to add script element to hidden head and remove.

Comment: I added extra details about the question.

Comment: @Paolo Stefan the firebug shows nothing executed with defined errors. I meant that executing the script on hidden `head` and remove the element and hidden `head` after the program execute, have to `head` section, ___one for user page and the other for execute the script___.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder I was just asking how to execute a script on hidden `head` section and remove them.

Comment: @KazuhiroYasui: *"have to head section, one for user page and the other for execute the script"* If you mean "two" rather than "to", note that [that is invalid HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a few typos, for instance you were not holding your new *Node* in a variable, and you were trying to append to an *undefined* variable.

```
var js = document.createElement('script'),
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
js.src = 'file.js'; // whatever
js.type = 'text/javascript';
head.appendChild(js);
head.removeChild(js);
```

In future, try opening your web console on the offending page and seeing if you get any error messages.

Comment: I corrected the 3rd. line. It was meant an exampale. However,on lines 5-6 `head.appendChild()` and `head.removeChild()` cause the script to added to `head` dynamically on the user side page. How to execute the function on the `head` element __behind__ the user page and remove, preferably using `ScriptManager` or `XMLHTTPRequest()`?

Comment: @KazuhiroYasui You mean like.. use _XMLHttpRequest_ to fetch, add the response as the contents of the `<script>`, add, remove? Or maybe even an `eval`? It is really difficult to understand what you are asking for.

Comment: I mean javascript `scriptmanager` to call js function and during the execution of the js function it should be on behind. Then, remove the script after.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy/paste your code or type it sloppily? It should be:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName( "head" )[ 0 ],
    js = document.createElement( "script" );
js.src = file;
js.type = "text/javascript";
head.appendChild( js );
```