# Execute javascript code as html

Tags: jquery

i want to execute jquery scripts in jquery html method.
Like

```
$(body).html("<div id='mydiv'></div><script>$('#mydiv').fadeIn();</script>");
```

or

```
$(body).append("<div id='mydiv'></div><script>$('#mydiv').fadeIn();</script>");
```

div is inserted but javascript code not run.

How code can be runned?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to do ? Could you be more specific ?

Comment: It's maybe because your java script is executed after the html loarding.
I'm not sur you can do it with DOM

Comment: You need to explain your actual problem. You are trying to solve it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this:

```
$(body).append("<div id='mydiv'></div>");
$('#mydiv').fadeIn();
```

After first line executing there are `mydiv` appears in DOM, so you can access it directly from your current script.

---

**Edit (after comments)**

If you want add script to you DOM using jQuery you should do it in some tricky way:

```
$("<script>$('#mydiv').fadeIn();</" + "script>").appendTo(document.body);
```

or

```
$("\x3Cscript>$('#mydiv').fadeIn();\x3C/script>").appendTo(document.body);
```

Without escaping or breaking `</script>` tag it terminates the entire script.

If you have more issues with your code please refer to next answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/1430055 where you can find explanations about debugging such a dynamic script, etc.

Comment: Yes, this is workong but iam want to put $(body).append(var); where var is variable with javascript code;

Comment: OK, in this case your question looks like duplicate. There is a detailed answer for the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3603496/1430055

Comment: Thankyou but this is only for scripts, iam want to put mixed contents. HTML text with javascript. Javascript is working but Jquery is not working. - $(body).append("<div id='mydiv'></div><script>alert();</script>"); is working, -  $(body).append("<div id='mydiv'></div><script>$('#mydiv').fadeIn();</script>"); - not working

Comment: I found another bug in your code. You are using incorrect jQuery selector for body tag. It should be enclosed in quotes. Please look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TBW9W/