# How to append a <script></script> along with other data returned from another page when using Jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading a reCaptcha using ajax. One of the lines in there from what gets returned from the other pages is the line below, and that line wont get loaded into my `div` when I use `$(.cap).html(callBack);`

**This is the line**

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n"></script>`

Is this something that jQuery disallows? Or am I doing something wrong? How can I solve this? How can I get jquery returned from another page, into my `<div>`?

What I'm testing with, is simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>No Tile</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQuery.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
.user {
    cursor: pointer;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$(".user").live("click",function() {
    $(".user").click(function() {

        data = "id=Hello"

        $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
               url:"demo.php",
              data:data,
          dataType:"html",

        beforeSend:function(html){

        },

        success: function(callBack){
            $(".cap").html(callBack);

            console.log(callBack);
        },

        error: function(page_data){

        },

        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

<div class="cap">Hello</div>

<span class="user">Add User</span>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the line returned from the other page that wont get loaded into the `div`.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n"></script>`

**The entire data returned**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n"></script>

    <noscript>
        <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
        <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
    </noscript>
```

Comment: $("head").append(callBack);

Comment: @Riturajratan Even with that the line I mentioned above does not append.

Comment: This is not possible the way you are trying.. There is a possible solution however, check out this previous post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element

Comment: @Tsasken Have you any idea how to add a </script> and other content after using the solution on this page? The entire thing is in the edit in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to return "script" tags, even in a string format. This is because of the way javascript works. You could however let your demo.php script return json. You should look that up yourself, but I don't believe there is another way to do this easily. 
(well, worse practice, you could just return a string and parse the values out of it but ...). Anyway, if you assume you return a json object in the following format, you could just copy paste the rest in your success function and alter the object name to 'callback' ...

```
var json = {
    type: "text/javascript",
    scriptSrc: "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n",
    id: "theFrame",
    iframeSrc: 'http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n'
};

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = json.type;
script.src = json.scriptSrc;

$('<iframe>', {
   src: json.iframeSrc,
   id:  json.id,
   frameborder: 0,
    height: 300,
    width: 500
   }).appendTo('.cap');
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vT3Ug/1/

Answer (score 1):

It actually **is** possible to render javascript tags. e.g. html5 boilertemplate uses it to see if it should load jQuery local or from CDN.

```
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
```

As you can see if you inject script tags you need to escape the closing script tag `<\/script>`.

On the other hand, you **can't** do this

```
<noscript>
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6LcXq-oSAAAAAOgwSIew_xq6xkv1QUxrZbRcMz6n" height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br/>
    <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge"/>
</noscript>
```

simply because you do not own the iframe source, your iframe won't get rendered.

But you could do something like this:

```
callBack = callBack.replace('</script','<\/script')
                   .replace('<noscript>','')
                   .replace('</noscript>','');

$('body').append(callback);
```