# How to inject Jquery into safari extension builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have done the global page file as

```
<script>  
safari.application.addEventListener("command", performCommand, false);  

function performCommand(event) {   
    if (event.command == "open-nettuts") {      
$('div.spaceball').hide();
    }  
}  
</script>
```

[image]

And in the start scripts I have put a `jquery.js` file. Why when I click on the toolbar button does it not hide the div with the `class="space ball"` on this [page](http://www.flickr.com/photos/absquatlate/6957283513/sizes/k/)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't access to web content, but you can inject js to page, wich modify something. See [Safari Extensions Development Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/SafariExtensionGuide.pdf) page 16.

To work on web content write in inject.js

```js
var script   = document.createElement("script");
script.type  = "text/javascript";
//script.src   = "path/to/your/javascript.js";    // use this for linked script
script.text  = "alert('voila!');"               // use this for inline script
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

See [Can't append  element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element).