# execute javascript which is returned via ajax request in RoR

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have such rails rendering javascript view:

```
$("##{@organization.id}-organization-introtext").hide();
$("##{@organization.id}-organization-full").append("#{escape_javascript(render @organization)}").hide().fadeIn('slow').focus();
```

and via it, for example i get such data:

```
$("#9-organization-introtext").hide();
$("#9-organization-full").append("<h2 id=\'magenta\'>\n  Shell - Автосервис\n<\/h2>\n<div>\n  Shell - Автосервис\n  <br>\n  <br>\n<\/div>\n<div>\n  <strong>\n    Контактная информация:\n  <\/strong>\n  <p>\n    8 (0152) 510 884\n    8 (029) 265 38 09\n  <\/p>\n  <p>\n    <script type=\"text/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\" src=\"//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=SrxOH8zh15XLRmFVDc91yCeDQr23_VUl&width=600&height=450\"><\/script>\n  <\/p>\n  <p>\n    г.Ростов-на-Дону, ул.Василевского 1\n  <\/p>\n<\/div>\n<div class=\'tags\'>\n  <span>\n    Метки:\n  <\/span>\n  автозапчасти, замена масла\n<\/div>\n").hide().fadeIn('slow').focus();
```

but in browser this script isn't executed, why? how to run it? and display this yandex.map ?

Answer (score 0):

Split the Javascript code and the HTML code from `@organization` and add the Javascript code to the `head` section of your document.

```
var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.text = "#{{escape_javascript(render @organization_javascript)}";
$("head").append( script );
```

Source - [Can't append <script> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/cant-append-script-element)

Comment: it's executed only onclick of link, and page is not reloading

Comment: i must append this to some block: $("##{@organization.id}-organization-full").   but your code append it all to head

Comment: note! that ajax returned code contain javascript and html code

Comment: so what do you think?

Comment: extract script code from the returned output and add it to the head